# How to Make Connections Look Better

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have created the following "table" as part of a larger document:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand*{\dd}[3][]{\tfrac{\mathrm{d}^{#1}#2}{\mathrm{d}#3^{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\D}[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d} #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5ex and 1em]
  \node (d0) {\(u\)};
  \node[right=of d0] (i0) {\(\D{v}\)};
  \node[below=of d0] (d1) {\(\dd{u}{x}\)};
  \node[right=of d1] (i1) {\(\int \D{v} \D{x}\)};
  \node[below=of d1] (d2) {\(\dd[2]{u}{x}\)};
  \node[right=of d2] (i2) {\(\int\left(\int\D{v}\D{x}\right)\D{x}\)};
  \node[below=of d2] (d3) {\(\cdots\)};
  \node[right=of d3] (i3) {\(\int\left(\int\left(\int\D{v}\D{x}\right)\D{x}%
    \right)\D{x}\)};
  \node[below=of i3] (i4) {\(\cdots\)};

  \draw (d0.east) -- (i1.west) (d1.east) -- (i2.west) (d2.east) -- (i3.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now this is okay (perhaps a little worse than that). How can I improve this design? I was thinking that to make the lines all straight making the first column right-aligned and the second column left-aligned would help, but I do not know how to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for, but here is one option is to use the `to` syntax and specify an `out=` and `in=` angles.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand*{\dd}[3][]{\tfrac{\mathrm{d}^{#1}#2}{\mathrm{d}#3^{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\D}[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d} #1}

\tikzset{My Line Style/.style={out=0, in=180, thick, blue, shorten <=-0.5ex, shorten >=-0.5ex, distance=1.0em, -stealth}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5ex and 1em]
  \node (d0) {\(u\)};
  \node[right=of d0] (i0) {\(\D{v}\)};
  \node[below=of d0] (d1) {\(\dd{u}{x}\)};
  \node[right=of d1] (i1) {\(\int \D{v} \D{x}\)};
  \node[below=of d1] (d2) {\(\dd[2]{u}{x}\)};
  \node[right=of d2] (i2) {\(\int\left(\int\D{v}\D{x}\right)\D{x}\)};
  \node[below=of d2] (d3) {\(\cdots\)};
  \node[right=of d3] (i3) {\(\int\left(\int\left(\int\D{v}\D{x}\right)\D{x}%
    \right)\D{x}\)};
  \node[below=of i3] (i4) {\(\cdots\)};

  \draw[My Line Style]  (d0.east) to (i1.west); 
  \draw[My Line Style]  (d1.east) to (i2.west);
  \draw[My Line Style]  (d2.east) to (i3.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah that does look somewhat better. I was thinking that if I also did those alignments the arrows would all be the same. Is there a way to make the first column right-aligned and the second left-aligned?

Comment: I would recommend you not try to do a table in `tikz`. Use a `tabular` environment for the table and use `tikzmark` to mark the points where you want to draw the lines to/from.  This example should get you started: [Inserting an image properly in a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45698/inserting-an-image-properly-in-a-table), but there are numerous other examples on this site.