# Illustrate distributive law with "broken" arrows

Tags: arrows

I would like to obtain the following formatting.

[image]

Comment: Related: [How to draw arrows between parts of an equation to show the Math Distributive Property (Multiplication)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35717/5764) and [Better solution to display the Distributive Property](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60763/5764)

Answer (score 11):

You could (ab-) use [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros)'s redox macros:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 \OX{first,$k$}(\OX{second,$a$}+\OX{third,$b$}) = ka + kb
\end{equation}
\redox(first,second)[->]{$\times$}
\redox(first,third)[->][-1]{$\times$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Neat! Just a quick suggestion -- if you prefixed `\scriptsize` to the two instances of `$\times$`, the multiplication symbol's size would be (slightly) better proportioned.

Comment: Sure, why not. I simply wanted to demonstrate the basic principle. :)