# tikz markers in a math equation of a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

I realize this is almost certainly impossible; however, I would love to see the TeX wizardry hidden here (and I actually also really desperately want this feature).

So I have a tikzpicture, and inside this picture, I have some node. Inside this, node, I have a math equation, say:

```
    $$\left|
        \frac{
          \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\right) \cdot
          \left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2\right)
        }{ (\sum_{i=1}^n \underbrace{a_ib_i}_{HERE})^2} \right| \geq 1$
```

Now, the underbrace gives me a nice rotated "}", and I can label it "HERE". However, I don't want to label it "HERE".

I want to draw an arrow from a tikzNode to where the "HERE" is located. I want to be able to do something like:

```
    \draw [->] (cauchySchwarzLabelNode) -- (HERE);
```

So basically, I need to be able to "grab the location of where 'HERE' is in the equation" ... and somehow draw an arrow to it from tikz.

Is there any hack to make this possible?

Comment: PS: I promise not to self answer this question within the next 30 days :-) This requires an understanding of tex/tikz internals far beyond my comprehension.

Comment: search for tikzmark questions and answers on the main site. An example :  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60763/better-solution-to-display-the-distributive-property

Comment: @percusse: nice, thanks! for some stupid reason I never thought it'd be named tikzmark

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `\subnode` command from the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) TikZ library.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117393/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node {\(\displaystyle\left|
        \frac{
          \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\right) \cdot
          \left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2\right)
        }{ (\sum_{i=1}^n \underbrace{a_ib_i}_{\subnode{brace}{}})^2} \right| \geq 1\)};
\draw[->] (-3,-3) to[out=0,in=-90] (brace.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I used `brace.north` because the subnode is actually the subscript of the underbrace, not the point of the underbrace itself.  Note the `remember picture` on the containing environment.

[image: arrow to underbrace]

Comment: Unrelated stupid question: I see lots of image examples on tex.stackexchange -- are people just taking screen shots, or is there some webservice on tex.stackexchange that auto renders TeX and crops it online?

Comment: @interactive_tikz: I guess we all take screen shots, no web service.

Comment: @interactive_tikz It used to be able to upload PDF, which led to many of us using the `standalone` class to generate the images.  But that doesn't work any more so I just take a screenshot.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how can I do the same thing in TikzEdt? I've tried the code in a simple Latex code, and it worked.Thanks.

Comment: @user2536125 I've never used TikzEdt so can't help you on that, I'm afraid.