# How to illustrate double distributive property?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

[image]

```
$\left(a+b\right)\left(c+d\right)=ac+ad+bc+bd$
```

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Better solution to display the Distributive Property](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60763/5764); [Draw arrows to show multiplication pattern (distributive property)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168972/5764); [How to draw arrows between parts of an equation to show the Math Distributive Property (Multiplication)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35717/5764)

Comment: @Werner thanks sir. But not same this picture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution using `tikzmark` library, instead of reinventing the wheel, like many old solutions you can find here.

[image: tikzmark ditributivity]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        every node/.style={outer sep=1pt},
        num/.style={draw,circle,fill=white,font=\tiny,inner sep=1pt}}
    
    \[
    (\tikzmarknode{A}{a}+\tikzmarknode{B}{b})(\tikzmarknode{C}{c}+\tikzmarknode{D}{d})=\tikzmarknode{AC}{ac}+\tikzmarknode{AD}{ad}+\tikzmarknode{BC}{bc}+\tikzmarknode{BD}{bd}
    \]
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,cyan]
        \draw[->] (A) to[out=60,in=100,looseness=1.5] node[num,pos=0.5] {1} (C) ;
        \draw[->] (A) to[out=60,in=110,looseness=1.8] node[num,pos=0.5] {2} (D) ;
        
        \draw[->] (B) to[out=-90,in=-100,looseness=1.6] node[num,pos=0.5] {3} (C) ;
        \draw[->] (B) to[out=-90,in=-110,looseness=1.9] node[num,pos=0.5] {4} (D) ;

        \foreach \n [count=\i] in {AC,AD,BC,BD}
            \node[num,above=10pt] at (\n.south) {\i};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hi. I am trying to do this for the following -> a(b + c) but I am honestly a little lost and there is constantly some error! Can you please help!? Thank you.