# Rainbow over numbers using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the MWE for creating an image below using `tikZ`. But it fails. Any idea to do that?

```
\documentclass[statementpaper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz} 


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[digits/.style={inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=2pt}]
    
    \node[digits] (num) at (0,0) {\large $23 \times 55$};
    
    \draw[<->,thick] ([xshift={width("$23$")+1ex/2}]num.north west) to [bend left=45] ([xshift={width("$23 \times 55$")-1ex/2}]num.north west);
    \draw[<->,thick] ([xshift={width("$2$")+1ex/2}]num.north west) to [bend left=45] node[above] (label above) {\small Multiply} ([xshift={width("$23 \times 5$")-1ex/2}]num.north west);

    \draw[<->,thick] ([xshift={width("$1$")-1ex/2}]num.south west) to [bend right=45] node[below] (label below) {\small Multiply} ([xshift={width("$114 \times 3$")-1ex/2}]num.south west);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Desired output:

[image]

**Note**: The question is not an exact duplicate of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610895/how-to-illustrate-double-distributive-property). Because, it actually deals with two numbers, not two mathematical expressions like the identified question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Draw arrows to show multiplication pattern (distributive property)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168972/5764)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to illustrate double distributive property?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610895/how-to-illustrate-double-distributive-property) (use of tikzmark)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As this is not really an exact duplicate, I answer to it, just to help you understand how a simple `tikzmark` implementation can help you in this kind of situation.

[image: tikzmark rainbow over numbers]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        every node/.style={outer sep=2pt},
        lab/.style={font=\tiny,inner sep=0pt}}
    
    \Huge 
    \[
    \tikzmarknode{A}{2}\tikzmarknode{B}{3} \times \tikzmarknode{C}{5}\tikzmarknode{D}{5}
    \]
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,line width=1.5pt]
        \draw[blue] (A) to[out=90,in=90,looseness=1.4] node[lab,midway,above]{multiply} (D) ;
        \draw[red] (B) to[out=90,in=90] node[lab,midway,above]{multiply} (C) ;  
        \draw[cyan] (A) to[out=-70,in=-110] node[lab,midway,below left]{multiply} (C) ;
        \draw[cyan] (B) to[out=-70,in=-110] node[lab,midway,below right]{multiply} (D) ;        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could put a rainbow like colors

Comment: I have thought of doing it ;)