# How to display single bracket distributive property using latex

Tags: amsmath

I am trying to recreate this (link) and there is already a page for the double brackets distributive property. I have tried to modify it and change a few things but I keep getting errors.

Here is the link to the page [How to illustrate double distributive property?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610895/how-to-illustrate-double-distributive-property)

I have got this so far:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\noindent The \textbf{distributive law} states that
\begin{align*}
a(b + c) &=  a \times b + a \times c\\
& = ab + ac
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As remarked in the answer, it would have been helpful if you'd noted how  you are trying to modify this code and what you are trying to achieve (and not make us follow a link to understand the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- it is unknown, how you try to change answer in given link
- If I understand correctly your problem, you only need to remove some arrows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                quotes,
                tikzmark}
\tikzset{
        is/.style = {inner ysep=2pt, minimum height=2ex},
       num/.style = {circle, draw, fill=white,font=\tiny,
                     inner sep=0.5pt, outer sep=1pt},
every edge/.style = {draw, -Straight Barb},
every edge quotes/.append style = {num, anchor=center}
       }

\begin{document}
    \[
\tikzmarknode[is]{A}{a}\cdot(\tikzmarknode[is]{B}{b} + \tikzmarknode[is]{C}{c})
    = \tikzmarknode{AB}{ab}+\tikzmarknode{AC}{ac}
    \]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, cyan]
\draw   (A.north) edge[out=60,in=120,looseness=2,"1"] (B.north)
        (A.north) edge[out=75,in=115,looseness=2,"2"] (C.north) ;
\foreach \n [count=\i] in {AB,AC}
    \node[num,above=10pt] at (\n.south) {\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: `cdot` is inserted that between `a` and `b` is more space for drawing arrow.

After three compilation above  MWE produces:

[image]

Is this what you after?

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! This is wonderful and quite perfect and I am able to change the numbers and everything!

Comment: @user292225, I'm glad to hear that anser help you!