# How can I make these arrows that point to something in the text?

Tags: arrows

How can I make these arrows that point to something in the text?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76506/134574

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263480/undersetting-an-arrow-beneath-an-equation

Comment: I would actually use the latest version of `tikzmark` for that, which comes with the `\tikzmarknode` macro.

Comment: where can I download it?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX-SE! I'd like to advertize `tikzmark` for that, which comes with the `\tikzmarknode` macro. (**EDIT**: Arrows reversed, big thanks to @KJO!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Gr}{Gr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
$\Gr(\tikzmarknode{f}{f})=\left\{\bigl(x,f(x)\bigr);~x\in A\right\}$
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[latex-] (f) |- ++(3em,-1.6em) node[right]{grafico de $f$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip\bigskip
$\displaystyle\lim_{\begin{smallmatrix}x\to x_0\\
x>x_0\end{smallmatrix}}f(x)=\tikzmarknode{L}{L}\dots$
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[latex-] (L) |- ++(3em,-1.6em) node[right]{numero real};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Me again :-) OP gave example with arrowheads other end of leaders, how can leaders be most easily reversed I got a result with `[-latex,<-]` but was that the correct way. PS worth mentioning two passes needed it threw me one or twice :-)

Comment: @KJO Thanks! Really appreciate it! (Yes, I am not looking very carefully after I think that the conceptual problem is solved, but I definitely should.)