# How do I add an arrow from one equation to another

Tags: math-mode, equations, tikz-arrows

I want to have something like this in LaTeX but I don't know how to add the labled arrow:

[image]

So the code I have is basically

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        x^4 &= x \cdot x \cdot x \cdot x \\
        x^3 &= x \cdot x \cdot x
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

and I want to add an arrow on the right hand side pointing from the second to the first equation and labled "$\cdot x$".

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!!. Take a look at this post (there are many other on this site): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76506/label-steps-of-equations-using-tikzmark

Comment: Have a look at the `witharrows` package.

Answer (score 8):

You could try the `witharrows` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}
$\begin{WithArrows}
x^4 &= x \cdot x \cdot x \cdot x \Arrow[tikz=<-]{${} \cdot x$} \\
x^3 &= x \cdot x \cdot x
\end{WithArrows}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to change the curvature or arrow tip of the arrow, you can style it using Ti*k*Z options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}
$\begin{WithArrows}
x^4 &= x \cdot x \cdot x \cdot x \Arrow[tikz={stealth-, in=100, out=80, looseness=1.5}]{${} \cdot x$} \\
x^3 &= x \cdot x \cdot x
\end{WithArrows}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The arrow doesn’t curl enough to point to the top equation. Can that be fixed?

Comment: @Simd Yes, see my edit.