# How create this flowchart?

Tags: diagrams

I want create this flowchart. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but you should provide at least a basic MWE that shows you put some effort in as well. And even if it looks like hell.

Comment: -1: You have not shown effort in any of your questions, despite of being advised to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use TikZ matrices for this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
  nodes={align=center,text width=2cm},
  row sep=2ex]{
Input            &               &                   & {Desired\\ Output}\\
Auto-Correlation &               & Cross-Correlation &                   \\
                 & Weiner Filter &                   &                   \\
                 & *             &                   &                   \\
                 & Actual Output &                   &                   \\
};

\begin{scope}[-latex]
\draw ($(m-1-1)!0.5!(m-1-1.west)$)--(m-1-1.west)|-
 ($(m-4-2.west)!0.5!(m-4-2)$);
\draw ($(m-1-1)!0.5!(m-1-1.east)$)--([xshift=1cm]m-1-1.east)|-
 ($(m-2-3.west)!0.3!(m-2-3)$);

\draw ($(m-1-4)!0.5!(m-1-4.west)$)--(m-1-4.west)|-
($(m-2-3.east)!0.3!(m-2-3)$);

\draw (m-2-1.south)|-($(m-3-2.west)!0.5!(m-3-2)$);
\draw (m-2-3.south)|-($(m-3-2.east)!0.5!(m-3-2)$);
\draw (m-3-2.south)--(m-4-2.north);
\draw (m-4-2.south)--(m-5-2.north);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

More information about the way to proceed can be found in [High level digital design in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110209/high-level-digital-design-in-tikz#110260).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but where is the arrow down 'input' ?!

Comment: @tanha: you're welcome :) For the arrow, I think you can add it quite easily, in the same way I connected `Weiner Filter` with `*` or `*` with `Actual Output` :)

Comment: Sorry i cant understand you :(
How to create the arrow down input ?

Comment: It is very simple: you have to draw a line from the input node (whose name is in the form m-<row>-<column>) to the second node. If you copy and paste one of the last lines of code in my example and you replace the correct name you will get it.

Comment: @ Claudio Fiandrino : Yohooooo i Success ,thanks a lot

Comment: @tanha: my pleasure :)

Comment: Sorry another question please,
How do I get line break in math expression?

Comment: @tanha: I think it is better if you post another question as the topic seems to be unrelated to the current one.