# Drawing arcs on a number line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I found this code in an answer to this question here [Help drawing a very simple number line using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148252/help-drawing-a-very-simple-number-line-using-tikz)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-latex] (-3.5,0) -- (3.5,0) ; %edit here for the axis
\foreach \x in  {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3} % edit here for the vertical lines
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
\foreach \x in {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3} % edit here for the numbers
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] 
{$\x$};
\draw[*-o] (0.92,0) -- (2.08,0);
\draw[very thick] (0.92,0) -- (1.92,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Could you explain how I can edit this to add directed arc-shaped arrows from one number to another? (Like those used for a sequence).

Comment: Maybe help this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168978/31034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line

```
\draw[*-o] (0.92,0) -- (2.08,0);
```

already draws an arrow. You only have to change the arrow head + tail (`->`), bend it (`bend left`), and change `--` to `to` (otherwise both coordinates get an arrow head):

```
\draw[->, bend left] (0.92,0) to (2.08,0);
```

alternatively use the `egde` command and style it accordingly

```
\draw (0.92,0) edge[->, bend left] (2.08,0);
```

The bending properties can be further specified by

- the angle in which it leaves a location, e.g. `bend left=90`.
- the distance of the bending edge with, e.g. `min distance=1cm`
- the looseness, which in this case is very similar to the distance, but behaves differently for loops, e.g. `looseness=3`

all together

```
\draw (0.92,0) edge[->, bend left=80, looseness=1.5] (2.08,0);
```

For more information have a look at the [pgf manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), Section 70.3

Comment: Is there a way that I can make the arrow bend more upwards as its looking a bit flat. Sorry but I have absolutely no experience at this.

Comment: Yes, I'll update the answer in a minute...