# Arrows over, under and around math text?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking to draw labeled arrows linking normal math text fragments like this with TikZ:

[image]

Comment: Related [How to draw arrows between parts of an equation to show the Math Distributive Property (Multiplication)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35717/how-to-draw-arrows-between-parts-of-an-equation-to-show-the-math-distributive-pr)

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168972/draw-arrows-to-show-multiplication-pattern-distributive-property/168978#168978

Comment: Welcome! What's the problem? Looks fairly straightforward. Presumably you have the text/maths in the nodes. Then what is the problem adding the arrows exactly? `arrows.meta` provides more arrow tips and customisation.

Comment: If you scroll down to answer #3 in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168972/draw-arrows-to-show-multiplication-pattern-distributive-property/168978#168978 you'll see that the image I posted looks a lot like the pstricks solution. I use a lot of HTML export from Org Mode so I need a TikZ solution, not a pstricks solution. Is a TikZ solution possible (that looks close to the pstricks solution or the image above)?

Answer (score 11):

A solution in TikZ, which sets the components of the math expression as series of nodes. Then the annotation labels are placed as nodes. Finally the arrows are drawn between the nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{bookman}
\begin{document}
% \[
%   \lambda x.\,(\lambda x.\, x\,y)\,
%   (x\,(\lambda x.\,\lambda y.\,y\,z\,x))
% \]
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  inner sep=0pt,
  outer sep=0pt,
  baseline=(lx_1.base),
]
  \path[every node/.append style={anchor=base west}]
    (0, 0)
    \foreach \name/\code in {
      lx_1/\lambda x,
      tmp/.\,(,
      lx_2/\lambda x,
      tmp/.\,,
      x_1/x,
      tmp/\,,
      y_1/y,
      tmp/)\,(,
      x_2/x,
      tmp/\,(,
      lx_3/\lambda x,
      tmp/.\,,
      ly_1/\lambda y,
      tmp/.\,,
      y_2/y,
      tmp/\,,
      z_1/z,
      tmp/\,,
      x_3/x,
      tmp/))%
    } {
      node (\name) {$\code$}
      (\name.base east)
    }
  ;
  \path[
    every node/.append style={
      anchor=base,
      font=\slshape\scriptsize,
    },
  ]
    % Annotation: frei
    (y_1.base) -- node[above=1.2\baselineskip] (frei) {frei} (z_1)
    % 4 annotations: gebunden
    (lx_1.base) -- node[below=3\baselineskip] (geb_1) {gebunden} (x_2)
    (lx_2.base) -- node[below=1.4\baselineskip] (geb_2) {gebunden} (x_1)
    (lx_3.base) -- node[below=3\baselineskip] (geb_3) {gebunden} (x_3)
    (ly_1.base) -- node[below=1.4\baselineskip] (geb_4) {gebunden} (y_2)
  ;
  \begin{scope}[
    >={Stealth[length=5pt]},
    thick,
    rounded corners=2pt,
    shorten <=.3em,
    shorten >=.3em,
  ]
    \draw[->] (frei) -| (y_1);
    \draw[->] (frei) -| (z_1);
    \def\GebArrow#1#2#3{
      \draw[->]
        (#2.north) ++(0, .3em) coordinate (tmp)
        (#1) |- (tmp) -| (#3)
      ;%
    }
    \GebArrow{x_2}{geb_1}{lx_1}
    \GebArrow{x_1}{geb_2}{lx_2}
    \GebArrow{x_3}{geb_3}{lx_3}
    \GebArrow{y_2}{geb_4}{ly_1}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]