# Automatically calculate width

Tags: spacing, automation, lengths

This is a question to [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35718/15874) to the question "[How to draw arrows between parts of an equation to show the Math Distributive Property (Multiplication)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35717/how-to-draw-arrows-between-parts-of-an-equation-to-show-the-math-distributive-pr)".

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c}
   \psDefBoxNodes{n1}{3}
  (\psDefBoxNodes{n2}{5x} +
   \psDefBoxNodes{n3}{4y} +
   \psDefBoxNodes{n4}{7z})
\end{array}
\psset{
  arrows = ->,
  nodesep = 3pt,
  arcangle = 60
}
\ncarc{n1:tC}{n2:tC}
\ncarc{n1:tC}{n3:tC}
\ncarc{n1:tC}{n4:tC}
\hspace{-0.55em} % The length is found manually but how can I make LaTeX calculate it automatically?
&= 3 \cdot 5x + 3 \cdot 4y + 3 \cdot 7z\\
&= 15x + 12y + 21z
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The question is incorporated as a comment in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use

   ```
   \begin{array}{c@{}}
   ```

   to remove the column spacing between the `array` and any surrounding environment. I'd actually `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}` instead, which would be similar to using the column specification `@{}c@{}`.
2. You need to use `\hspace{-\arraycolsep}` or remove the column gap inserted by `array`.

<sub>There's not real need for using an `array` in your example, but that's perhaps not really a question here.</sub>