# Draw arches between variables

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: pregroup grammar]

I want to draw arches (possibly overlapping or nested) between variables, in an equation, and the line straight down. A replication of the image above.

If possible I would like the arches to have labels and words displayed above the variables.

I did not succeed with tikz.

Comment: Is this supposed to be used in text?

Comment: No as an equation. I'll edit.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35717/how-to-draw-arrows-between-parts-of-an-equation-to-show-the-math-distributive-pr should be a reasonable starting point.

Comment: I tried http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61990/96535, but did not get the line straight down. And everything shifted everytime I adjusted something. I was hoping for a solution that takes a source and target and drawing wherever they are.

Comment: Can you add an example of such an equation you want to use? Also: should the lines only go above or below too? That's not very clear.

Comment: I want to replicate the example image. I will edit to make that more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea, similar to the solutions at [How to draw arrows between parts of an equation to show the Math Distributive Property (Multiplication)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35717/how-to-draw-arrows-between-parts-of-an-equation-to-show-the-math-distributive-pr)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mtm/.style={
  remember picture,
  inner sep=0pt,
  outer ysep=0.1em,
}}
\newcommand\mtm[2]{\tikz[mtm] \node[anchor=base] (#1) {$#2\mathstrut$};}

\begin{document}
Test text test text test text.
Test text test text test text.
Test text test text test text.
Test text test text test text.
\begin{equation}
  \mtm{n}{n} \quad \mtm{nr}{n^r} \mathbin{} \mtm{s}{s} \mathbin{} 
    \mtm{nl}{n^l} \quad \mtm{n2}{n}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,looseness=1.8,overlay,remember picture]
    \draw (n.south) to[out=-90,in=-90] (nr.south);
    \draw (s.south) -- ++(0,-2em);
    \draw (nl.south) to[out=-90,in=-90] (n2.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{1.5em} % to allow space for the descending line
\end{equation}
Test text test text test text.
Test text test text test text.
Test text test text test text.
Test text test text test text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Explanation of the code

```
\tikzset{mtm/.style={
  remember picture,
  inner sep=0pt,
  outer ysep=0.1em,
}}
```

A style to use throughout `mtm` ("math Ti*k*Z mark") nodes. `remember picture` is needed so the node names can be referred to later by our overall drawing. `inner sep=0pt` ensures that math spacing is not affected. `outer ysep=0.1em` adds a bit of padding between the line we draw later and the math variable.

```
\newcommand\mtm[2]{\tikz[mtm] \node[anchor=base] (#1) {$#2\mathstrut$};}
```

A macro to place our "math Ti*k*Z mark" nodes. It accepts 2 arguments. The first is the node name (which we'll use later). The second is the node contents to print, assuming we're in a math mode context. `anchor=base` and `\mathstrut` just to cover all bases for alignment with subscripts/superscripts/ascenders/descenders/etc.

```
\begin{equation}
  \mtm{n}{n} \quad \mtm{nr}{n^r} \mathbin{} \mtm{s}{s} \mathbin{} 
    \mtm{nl}{n^l} \quad \mtm{n2}{n}
```

Within the equation, we write things normally (I added manual spacing commands to approximate the spacing in your image; I assume you have a more formal way of specifying what these spaces should be). Except, wherever there is a variable we need to use in the drawing (for example `n`) we use `\mtm{n}{n}`. The node names must be unique, so for the second `n`, we use `mtm{n2}{n}` where `n2` is the node name for this second `n`.

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,looseness=1.8,overlay,remember picture]
    \draw (n.south) to[out=-90,in=-90] (nr.south);
    \draw (s.south) -- ++(0,-2em);
    \draw (nl.south) to[out=-90,in=-90] (n2.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

After we finish writing the equation, we add a `tikzpicture` to place the annotations. `overlay,remember picture` are required so the picture can be placed over the already-typeset mathematics and refer back to those node names.

```
  \vspace{1.5em} % to allow space for the descending line
\end{equation}
```

At the end of the equation, we have to add some extra space to leave room for the `tikzpicture` since it doesn't take up any "space" on the page.

## Caveats

`\displaystyle` for fractions, operator limits, spacing, etc. will be lost, since I enter inline math inside the nodes. You could add this to the definition of `\mtm` if desired, though it doesn't matter for this use case.

The `\vspace` amount has to be tuned per picture—if the size of your annotations changes, the extra space will have to change as well.

Comment: Thanks, this is tremendously helpful! Exactly what I wanted https://i.imgur.com/PD3buml.png