# Draw arrows between elements inside math matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, article

I want to make this,

[image]

without having to do the entire thing in TikZ. I tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35717/how-to-draw-arrows-between-parts-of-an-equation-to-show-the-math-distributive-pr) (pst-node), which sort of worked, but then I had to use the Basic Builder and I want to avoid that.

Also I tried to make the arrows with TikZ, but I wasn't able to shift the tikzpicture into the equation environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,norsk, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{matrix}
            x_1&y_1&z_1&x_1&y_1&z_1\\
            x_2&y_2&z_2&x_2&y_2&z_2
        \end{matrix}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the `Basic Builder`?

Comment: I'm using sublime text to develop the document. There's several ways to compile, one, that gives me at the time several compile-warnings and does not support makeindex, is the Basic Builder which simply runs xelatex and bibtex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question reads **“without having to do the *entire* thing in TikZ”**, so here is a solution that keeps the original `matrix`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,norsk, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\rn}[2]{%% "rn": "remember node"
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]\node [inner sep=0] (#1) {$#2$};%
}

\begin{document}
    %% The original matrix, but with commands to remember the nodes:
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{matrix}
            x_1 & \rn{11}{y_1} & \rn{12}{z_1} & \rn{13}{x_1} & \rn{14}{y_1} & z_1
        \\
            x_2 & \rn{21}{y_2} & \rn{22}{z_2} & \rn{23}{x_2} & \rn{24}{y_2} & z_2
        \end{matrix}
    \end{equation*}

    %% Draw the arrows:
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw [->] (11) -- (22);
        \draw [->] (12) -- (23);
        \draw [->] (13) -- (24);
        \draw [->] (21) -- (12);
        \draw [->] (22) -- (13);
        \draw [->] (23) -- (14);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Explanation:**
The command `\rn` puts its second argument in a `tikz` node. The option `remember picture` makes these nodes available even after the mini tikzpicture, i.e., after the equation.
Later, another tikzpicture draws the arrows. The option `overlay` ensures that it takes no space and can draw on top of the matrix above.

It looks like before, but with the desired arrows:
[image: result]

Answer (score 8):

tikz-cd can be used for this. Up-right arrows are drawn by `\arrow[ur]` and Down-right arrows are drawn by `\arrow[dr]`. Normal tikz options apply here. You can control `row sep` and `column sep` by specifying any lengths for them, or simply use `[cramped, sep=small]` as a fast key.

```
\documentclass[12pt,norsk, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzcd}[cramped, sep=small]
    x_1 & y_1\arrow[dr] & z_1\arrow[dr] & x_1\arrow[dr] & y_1 & z_1 \\
    x_2 & y_2\arrow[ur] & z_2\arrow[ur] & x_2\arrow[ur] & y_2 & z_2
  \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: More symmetric arrows would be nicer.

Answer (score 8):

Without `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath,graphicx,tabstackengine}
\newcommand\crisscross{\ooalign{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{30}{${-}\mkern-4mu{-}\mkern-4mu{\rightarrow}$}\cr
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{-30}{${-}\mkern-4mu{-}\mkern-4mu{\rightarrow}$}}
}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\[
{}={}\tabbedCenterstack{
  x_1&&y_1&&z_1&&x_1&&y_1&&z_1\\
  &\phantom{\crisscross}&&\crisscross&&\crisscross&&\crisscross&&\phantom{\crisscross}&\\
  x_2&&y_2&&z_2&&x_2&&y_2&&z_2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

with pure `tikz`

```
\documentclass[12pt,norsk, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix  (m) [matrix of math nodes,
              nodes={inner sep=1pt},
              column sep=2ex, row sep=2ex]
{
    x_1&y_1&z_1&x_1&y_1&z_1\\
    x_2&y_2&z_2&x_2&y_2&z_2\\
 };
\draw[->]  (m-1-2) edge (m-2-3)    (m-1-3) edge (m-2-4)    (m-1-4) edge (m-2-5)
            (m-2-2) edge (m-1-3)    (m-2-3) edge (m-1-4)    (m-2-4) edge (m-1-5);

 \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,norsk, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, pgffor}
\usepackage{pst-node}%, auto-pst-pdf

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
    \begin{equation*}
    \setlength{\arraycolsep}{8pt}
        \begin{matrix}
            x_1&\Rnode{A1}{y_1}&\Rnode{B1}{z_1}&\Rnode{C1}{x_1}&\Rnode{D1}{y_1}&z_1\\
            x_2&\Rnode{A2}{y_2}&\Rnode{B2}{z_2}&\Rnode{C2}{x_2}&\Rnode{D2}{y_2}&z_2
        \end{matrix}
\psset{arrowinset=0.12, arrows=->, linewidth=0.6pt, nodesepB=0.8pt}
\foreach \L/\M in {A1/B2, B1/C2, C1/D2}{\ncline{\L}{\M}}
\psset{nodesepB=-0.2pt}
\foreach \L/\M in {A2/B1,B2/C1, C2/D1}{\ncline{\L}{\M}}
    \end{equation*}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to the classical environment `{matrix}` of `amsmath` but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells. You can use those nodes with Tikz to draw whatever rule or arrow you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$= \begin{NiceMatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & x_1 & y_1 & z_1 \\[2mm]
x_2 & y_2 & z_2 & x_2 & y_2 & z_2 
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [shorten > = 1mm, shorten < = 1mm,->]
  \draw (1-2) -- (2-3) ; 
  \draw (1-3) -- (2-4) ; 
  \draw (1-4) -- (2-5) ; 
  \draw (2-2) -- (1-3) ; 
  \draw (2-3) -- (1-4) ; 
  \draw (2-4) -- (1-5) ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]