# How to create a cost matrix?

Tags: formatting, packages, matrices

I need to create a cost matrix and a trace like in the image below. I found nothing that seemed up to the task in the matrix package. Is this possible in LaTeX?

[image: Example of cost matrix]

Comment: What is a cost matrix?

Comment: You can try to use `nicematrix` that allows to easily use TikZ to draw the arrows. What would be the way to type the left table ? Make LaTeX calculate the path for the arrows will be more challenging but feasible (but not by me for the moment).

Comment: Look at the matrix on the left. You have two strings "ABABBB" and "BABAAA". The distance between the two strings can be described using the  [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). The value (n,m) in a cost matrix with the size n*m is the minimum cost to transform string one to string two.
You can then get an optimal edit sequence by tracing the route towards (0,0) using the smallest values on the way.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want this matrix to be built automatically when we give any two strings of characters according to the algorithm indicated in the link.

Comment: @AndréC I am okay with calculating the values myself, I just need a way to create the visualization.

Comment: You want to build the left matrix and not the right figure called `Trace`, is that right?

Comment: @AndréC Ideally I want to build both. However, the left matrix could suffice.

Comment: https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=1fxt  ----- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361375/how-to-add-arrow-in-equations-and-matrix  -----   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387703/draw-arrows-between-elements-inside-math-matrix

Comment: @A-wels I ask you to accept the other answer which seems to me better suited and simpler.

Comment: Shouldn't the 6 in the bottom right hand corner be 5? Looking at the earlier adjacent entries we get `min{4+1,5+1,5+1}=5`. There seem to be other problems as well.

Comment: @A-wels The calculation of the matrix could be easily implemented using LuaTeX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of different packages and therefore a lot of possibilities to do this. Here is one with the `matrix` library of the `TikZ` package.

## Update 1 : problem on a arrow

The first code reverses an arrow and I haven't figured out why yet. To correct this, the code becomes heavier.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[length=4pt]}]
\matrix (cost)[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells]
{ & & B & A & B & A & A & A \\
  & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
A & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
B & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
A & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
B & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
B & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
B & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\  
};
\draw (cost-1-8.south east) -| (cost-8-1.south east)-| cycle;
\draw (cost-2-8.south east) -| (cost-8-2.south east);
\foreach \x/\y [remember =\x as \lastx (initially 8),remember=\y as \lasty (initially 8)] in {7/7,6/6}{
 \draw[->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt](cost-\lastx-\lasty)--(cost-\x-\y);
 }
 
 \draw[<-,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (cost-6-6)--(cost-5-6);
\foreach \x/\y [remember =\x as \lastx (initially 5),remember=\y as \lasty (initially 6)] in {4/5,3/4,2/3,2/2}{
 \draw[->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt](cost-\lastx-\lasty)--(cost-\x-\y);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[length=4pt]}]
\matrix (cost)[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells]
{ & & B & A & B & A & A & A \\
  & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
A & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
B & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
A & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
B & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
B & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
B & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\  
};
\draw (cost-1-8.south east) -| (cost-8-1.south east)-| cycle;
\draw (cost-2-8.south east) -| (cost-8-2.south east);
\foreach \x/\y [remember =\x as \lastx (initially 8),remember=\y as \lasty (initially 8)] in {7/7,6/6,5/6,4/5,3/4,2/3,2/2}{
 \draw[->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt](cost-\lastx-\lasty)--(cost-\x-\y);
 }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

With `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|ccccccc|}[first-row,first-col]
  &   & B & A & B & A & A & A \\
\hline
  & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
A & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
B & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
A & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
B & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
B & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
B & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\  
\hline
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (8-|2) |- (2-|8) ;
\begin{scope}[->,shorten < = 1pt, shorten > = 1pt]
\draw (1-2) -- (1-1) ;
\draw (2-3) -- (1-2) ;
\draw (3-4) -- (2-3) ;
\draw (4-5) -- (3-4) ;
\draw (5-5) -- (4-5) ;
\draw (6-6) -- (5-5) ;
\draw (7-7) -- (6-6) ;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 4):

A solution for both images, based  on ordinary tabulars and the help of `pstricks` for the connections:

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-node, multido} 

\begin{document}

\sffamily\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
 { \begin{tabular}[t]{c|c|*{6}{c}|}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{}B & A & B & A & A & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} \\
\cline{2-8}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rnode{8}{0}} & \rnode{7}{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 \cline{3-8}
 A & 1 & 2 & \rnode{6}{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\[2pt]
 B & 2 & 1 & 2 & \rnode{5}{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[2pt]
 A & 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & \rnode{4}{1} & 2 & 3 \\[2pt]
 B & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & \rnode{3}{2} & 3 & 4 \\[2pt]
 B & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 3 & \rnode{2}{4} & 5 \\[2pt]
 B & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \rnode{1}{6} \\
\cline{2-8}
\end{tabular}
\psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12,linejoin=1, nodesep=1pt}
\multido{\is=1+1,\it=2+1}{7}{\ncline{\is}{\it}}}
 &
{\Large Trace\bigskip}\newline
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}\begin{tabular}[t]{*{6}{c}}
  A & B & A & B & B & B \\[-1ex]
\pnode{U1} & \pnode{U2} & \pnode{U3} & & \pnode{U4} & \pnode{U5}\\[1em]
 & \pnode{D1} & \pnode{D2} & \pnode{D3} & \pnode{D4} & \pnode{D5}\\
B & A & B & A & A & A
\end{tabular}}
\multido{\i=1+1}{5}{\ncline{D\i}{U\i}}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I love `PStricks` +1....

Comment: @MadyYuvi: What I appreciate in pstricks is that pstricks code can be included in ordinary environments without perturbating whatever, and further, contrary to TiKZ, it uses a LaTeX syntax.