# Tikz matrix library: Corner to corner arrows between cells may come in reverse order

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

When the `matrix` library is loaded and the `matrix of nodes` key is activated, each node can be accessed according to the `name-row-column` syntax.

In some cases, the arrows are built in the **opposite direction** of what is requested.
To illustrate this, I have **colored in red** the arrows that are drawn in the **opposite direction** of what is requested.

I colored the **background of the cells** from which the **arrows start in blue**.

## Update without `shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt`

By default, when cells are placed side by side, the arrows are reversed.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes]
{
8 & 1 & 6 \\
3 & 5 & 7 \\
4 & 9 & 2 \\
};
\draw[thick,blue,->] (magic-1-1) |- (magic-2-3);
\draw[thick,blue,->] (magic-1-1) -- (magic-2-3);
\draw[thick,red,->] (magic-1-1) -- (magic-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes,
row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}},
row 2 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}},
row 4 column 1/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}},
row 1 column 5/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}},
row 2 column 6/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}},
row 3 column 5/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}},
row 4 column 6/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}},
row 7 column 4/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}},
row 4 column 4/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}}]
{
8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8\\
3 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 6 & 5\\
4 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 4 \\
4 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 3 \\
8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8\\
3 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 6 & 5\\
4 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 4 \\
4 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 3 \\
};
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-1-1) |- (magic-2-2);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-1-1) -- (magic-2-2);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-1-1) -| (magic-2-2);


\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-4-4) |- (magic-3-3);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-4-4) -- (magic-3-3);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-4-4) -| (magic-3-3);

\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-4-1) -- (magic-3-2);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-4-1) |- (magic-3-2);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-4-1) -| (magic-3-2);

\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-2-3) -- (magic-1-4);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-2-3) |- (magic-1-4);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-2-3) -| (magic-1-4);

\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-1-5) -- (magic-2-5);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-2-6) -- (magic-1-6);

\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-3-5) -- (magic-3-6);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-4-6) -- (magic-4-5);

\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-6-1);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-6-2);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-6-3);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-6-4);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-6-5);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-6-6);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-6-7);

\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-8-1);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-8-2);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-8-3);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-8-4);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-8-5);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-8-6);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-8-7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to choose a different title that makes this easer to find in the future.

Comment: As I am not English-speaking, please change the title to suit you.

Comment: That is a funny one, try adding `row sep=1em, column sep=1em,` then it works. It might be a combination of (1) each box basically touching and (2)  you using `-3pt` and and we are drawing from the edge of the boxes. The negative shorten then ens up sitting on opposite sides of the boxes and the arrow is reversed

Comment: Also it works correctly then between `.center`

Comment: If i delete `shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt` then, the arrows are drawn but in the wrong direction. It is then necessary to space the rows and the columns so that it becomes normal again as you did.

Comment: This is an example why mentioning the word `bug` in the title is not a good idea ;-)

Comment: @AndréC What is the use of this ?

Comment: @projetmbc I had this problem when I wanted to create a foreach loop to build an arrow path here [How to create a cost matrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558500/138900), I had to make the code heavier to avoid this problem.

Comment: Oh, stumpled on something, try setting `outer sep=0pt` then it works. It is seems to be using `outer sep` as a limit as to then the switch happens, if inside then it switches

Comment: Also it has nothing to do with the `matrix` library. It can be done with normal nodes.

Comment: @daleif Can you give an answer that explains when this happens and the minimum condition that solves this problem?

Comment: Not really as I'm not 100% sure. I just found some strange values.

Comment: @daleif I think like you that the problem is certainly due to an approximation of the coordinates of the edges of the nodes. The track of `outer sep` or so of `column sep` and `row sep` seems to me to need to be explored further. The ideal would be to find the exact cause so that you can propose a fix in the TikZ repository.

Comment: @daleif In my opinion, inner anchors should be added to the node like `north text`, `south text` `north east text` *(there is an anchor called `text` as shown in the `shape` library)*. This would allow the arrows to start not from the node boundary, but from the text boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line-drawing operations of TikZ are pretty smart
when node names are used as start or target coordinates because TikZ takes a point on the border of the node for the real start or target point.

As smart as this it, it will produce not the best lines when the nodes are too close to each other (or too big).

When `(a) -- (b)` is used TikZ asks PGF

- for the point on the border of `a` that is in
  the direction of `b`'s center (i.e. `b.center`) and
- for the point on the border of `b` that is in
  the direction of `a`'s center.

Take a look at this example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, nodes={draw,gray}]
\node (a) {a};
\node at (.1,1) (b) {b};
\draw (a) |- (b);

\tikzset{xshift=1cm}
\node[blue] (a) {a};
\node[green] at (.1,.4) (b) {b};
\draw[thick, shorten >=-3pt, shorten <=-3pt] (a) -- (b);
\draw[red] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

The red arrow in the right part starts at the border of `a`
and goes to the border of `b` (that's what you asked for with `(a) -- (b)`).

(The `shorten`ing of the path is done much later in the process and can't help you here.)

Similar things happen with the `-|` and `|-` path operators.
When TikZ finds `(a) |- (b)` it asks PGF

- for the point on the border of `a` that is either upwards
  (when `b` is above `a` in the current coordinate system)
  or downwards (when `b` is below `a`) and
- for the point on the border of `b` that is either to the left
  (when `a` is to the left of `b`)
  or to the right (when `a` is to the right of `b`).

Since `a` is every so lightly left of `b`
it choose the left most point on the border
even if it is more to the left than `a`'s center.

---

But where is that border actually?
With the default settings of PGF/TikZ
the border lies on the outside of the shape's path.

But we can change that in relation to the shape's path,
this is what the values of `/pgf/outer xsep` and `/pgf/outer ysep` are for.
In fact, by default, this is set to `.5\pgflinewidth`
so that the border lies exactly at the edge of the line.

So, instead of `shorten`ing the path
we can just make the border smaller than the shape by using, say

```
outer sep = -3pt
```

I've chosen `-.1666em` in the example because I think it looks better and it is half the length of the default `inner sep`s (the space between text and the shape's path).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->, nodes={draw,gray}]
\node (a) {a};
\node at (.1,1) (b) {b};
\draw (a) |- (b);

\tikzset{xshift=1cm}
\node[blue] (a) {a};
\node[green] at (.1,.4) (b) {b};
\draw[thick, shorten >=-3pt, shorten <=-3pt] (a) -- (b);
\draw[red] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  rc/.style 2 args={
    @/.style args={r##1c##2}{row ##1 column ##2/.append style={#2}},
    @/.list={#1}}
]
\matrix (magic) [
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes={outer sep=-.1666em},
  rc={r1c1, r2c3, r4c1, r1c5, r2c6, r3c5, r4c6, r7c4, r4c4}
     {nodes={fill=blue!20}},
] {
    8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 \\
    3 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 6 & 5 \\
    4 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 4 \\
    4 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 3 \\
    8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 \\
    3 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 6 & 5 \\
    4 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 4 \\
    4 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 3 \\
};

\begin{scope}[thick, ->]
    \draw[blue] (magic-1-1) |- (magic-2-2);
    \draw[red] (magic-1-1) -- (magic-2-2);
    \draw[blue] (magic-1-1) -| (magic-2-2);
    
    \draw[blue] (magic-4-4) |- (magic-3-3);
    \draw[red] (magic-4-4) -- (magic-3-3);
    \draw[blue] (magic-4-4) -| (magic-3-3);
    
    \draw[red] (magic-4-1) -- (magic-3-2);
    \draw[blue] (magic-4-1) |- (magic-3-2);
    \draw[blue] (magic-4-1) -| (magic-3-2);
    
    \draw[red] (magic-2-3) -- (magic-1-4);
    \draw[blue] (magic-2-3) |- (magic-1-4);
    \draw[blue] (magic-2-3) -| (magic-1-4);
    
    \draw[red] (magic-1-5) -- (magic-2-5);
    \draw[red] (magic-2-6) -- (magic-1-6);
    
    \draw[red] (magic-3-5) -- (magic-3-6);
    \draw[red] (magic-4-6) -- (magic-4-5);
    
    \foreach \row in {6, 8} {
      \path[blue] (magic-7-4) edge (magic-\row-1)
                              edge (magic-\row-2)
                              edge (magic-\row-6)
                              edge (magic-\row-7);
      \path[red]  (magic-7-4) edge (magic-\row-3)
                              edge (magic-\row-4)
                              edge (magic-\row-5);
    }
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The nodes touch each other.

With `inner sep=0pt`, I create smaller nodes and I use `row sep` and `column sep` to separate them.

With `shorten > =0pt` and `shorten < = 0pt`, I draw the ``exact'' arrows between the nodes and they are as expected (with nodes which don't touche each other).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes,inner sep = 0pt, row sep = 2mm, column sep  =2mm,
row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}},
row 2 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}},
row 4 column 1/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}},
row 1 column 5/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}},
row 2 column 6/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}},
row 3 column 5/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}},
row 4 column 6/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}},
row 7 column 4/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}},
row 4 column 4/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}}]
{
8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8\\
3 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 6 & 5\\
4 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 4 \\
4 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 3 \\
8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8\\
3 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 7 & 6 & 5\\
4 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 4 \\
4 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 3 \\
};
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-1-1) |- (magic-2-2);
\draw[thick,red, ->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-1-1) -- (magic-2-2);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-1-1) -| (magic-2-2);


\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-4-4) |- (magic-3-3);
\draw[thick,red, ->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-4-4) -- (magic-3-3);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-4-4) -| (magic-3-3);

\draw[thick,red, ->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-4-1) -- (magic-3-2);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-4-1) |- (magic-3-2);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-4-1) -| (magic-3-2);

\draw[thick,red, ->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-2-3) -- (magic-1-4);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-2-3) |- (magic-1-4);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-2-3) -| (magic-1-4);

\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-1-5) -- (magic-2-5);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-2-6) -- (magic-1-6);

\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-3-5) -- (magic-3-6);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-4-6) -- (magic-4-5);

\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-6-1);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-6-2);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-6-3);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-6-4);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-6-5);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-6-6);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-6-7);

\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-8-1);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-8-2);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-8-3);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-8-4);
\draw[thick,red,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-8-5);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-8-6);
\draw[thick,blue,->,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=0pt] (magic-7-4) -- (magic-8-7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Yes, but if we do not space the rows and columns, the arrows are sometimes drawn in opposite directions.

Comment: To pag. 29 of your package there is a word in French language. "Here is an example of **utilisation**":-)

Comment: Can you explain why the negative shorten ends up placing the ends of the arrows out side the box? Might be that shorten for negative values aren't that welldefined

Comment: @Sebastiano which package?

Comment: @daleif nicematrix :-)...package

Comment: If `magic-1-1` touches `magic-1-2`, I think that Tikz will try to draw a rule from `magic-1-1.east` to `magic-1-2.west`. Since it's the same point, the straight line between both is not defined and, absolutetly, it's not possible to draw an arrow between both, even using `shorten <` and `shorten >`. Tikz draws something but I think that it must be considered as unpredictable.

Comment: @Sebastiano. I will correct (you should have sent me an email).

Comment: It looks a lot like the points chosen for the arrow are `-1-1 +(3pt,-3pt)` and `-2-2 +(-3pt,3pt)`

Comment: When drawing a line between two nodes, PGF uses `\pgfpointshapeborder`. In `pgfmanual.pdf` (p. 1123), it is said :
`This command returns the point on the border of the shape that lies on a straight line from the center of the node to hpointi. For complex shapes it is not guaranteed that this point will actually lie on the border, it may be on the border of a “simplified” version of the shape.` I don't know the exact computations...

Comment: It is just strange that it looks like the ends are given `+3pt` not `-3pt`

Comment: Try with `outer sep=0pt` then it works. Seems `outer sep` is used as some kind of threshold here.

Comment: Probably that, when the nodes touch each other, the (initial) positive value of `outer sep` makes that the two points used as extremities of the line to draw are in the reverse order (compared to the position of the nodes). Sounds logical.

Comment: Lol, with the right distance one can even make the arrow horizontal. #notdefined

Comment: @F.Pantigny Now I have sent you the email.