# Boxing in cases environment

Tags: cases

I'm working with a system

```
$$\begin{cases}
Ax+By   & = C\\
Dx+Ey   & = F
\end{cases}$$
```

Is there a way to put a box around A & D, around B & E, and around C & F within the system?

Comment: You could use `tikzpicture` to print your equation and functionality `rememberpictureoverlay` and then you can add boxes arrows, symbols... whatever you want to make it appear as you wish

Comment: As always: also don't use `$$...$$` that is not LaTeX syntax

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In my TeXworks $$...$$ is the math display environment.

Comment: `$$` is primitive tex syntax but it should not be used in a latex document. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69854/1090

Comment: See my answer: I using `\[` and  `\]` to have what you want. This is what @DavidCarlisle says

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}

\makeatletter
\xdef\myfsize{\f@size}
\makeatother



\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawRect}[4]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[#3] ([yshift={\myfsize/1.5},xshift=#4]#1.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-#4]#2.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{cases}
\tikzmark{a}A x+ \tikzmark{c}B y   & = \tikzmark{e} C\\
D\tikzmark{b} x+E\tikzmark{d} y   & = F\tikzmark{f}
\DrawRect{a}{b}{green}{4pt}\DrawRect{c}{d}{red}{4pt}\DrawRect{e}{f}{black}{4pt}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

The above gives the same results but finds automatically the fontsize to use it as yshift and has an extra argument that reduces the box on x axis (a negative value will increase it)

**Source of code that I changed: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35718/120578**

**Old answer**
A fast solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawRect}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[#3] ([yshift=8pt,xshift=4pt]#1.north west) rectangle ([yshift=0pt,xshift=-4pt]#2.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

\[\begin{cases}
\tikzmark{a} A x+ \tikzmark{c} B y   & = \tikzmark{e} C\\
D \tikzmark{b} x+E\tikzmark{d} y   & = F\tikzmark{f}
\DrawRect{a}{b}{green}\DrawRect{c}{d}{red}\DrawRect{e}{f}{black}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Can be improved but I adding it to get my comment's point.

Result:

[image]