# How to put a box around only part of an aligned equation set

Tags: empheq

I have the following aligned equation set

```
\begin{subequations}\label{1}
\begin{align}
&A=B=C\label{a}\\
&D=E=F\label{b}
\end{align}}
\end{subequations}
```

I want to put the part

> A=B
>
> D=E

In a single box, leaving the

> =C

and

> =F

out of the box.

Can this be done, using empheq, for example?

Comment: sorry, there should be \\ after label{a}

Comment: Please check this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389332/120578 if you put a `\tikzmark` before `A` and another one after `E` you got it.

Answer (score 3):

This is the code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawRect}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[#3] ([yshift=8pt,xshift=4pt]#1.north west) rectangle ([yshift=0pt,xshift=-4pt]#2.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{1}
\begin{align}
&\tikzmark{Begin}A=B=C\label{a}\\
&D=E\tikzmark{End}=F\label{b}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\DrawRect{Begin}{End}{green}
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]

**Edit for more complicated situations:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[xshift={\f@size/1.5},yshift={\f@size/3}] (#1) {\phantom{$#2$}};}
\makeatother

% #1 is the draw option (can contain decorate etc) #2 can be any shift option to be used for all points. #3 are the points in comma separated list. 
\def\DrawComplic#1#2#3{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
   \draw[#1]\foreach \point[count=\i from 0] in {#3}{%
   \ifnum\i=0 ([#2]\point) \else --([#2]\point)\fi%
   }--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{1}
\begin{align}
f(x,y,z)&=\tikzmark{First}{A x}A x=B y=C z\label{a}\\
&=\tikzmark{Fourth}{D x}D x=\tikzmark{Third}{E y}E y=F z\label{b}\\
&=\tikzmark{Last}{F x}F x=G y\label{c}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\DrawComplic{red}{}{First.north west,First.north east,First.south east,Third.north east,Third.south east,Last.north east, Last.south east, Last.south west}
 \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Actually my expressions are much more complicated and I need a command that will adapt to any expression

Comment: @Ehud: I think your answer is been answered for the way it asked and it may be useful for other users later. You have two answers that both solves the problem. If you need something more complicated feel free to open a new answer or at least to edit this one (even if I feel that this will be useful to other people...) [For this reason I suggest If you will not open a new question to make an "Edit" below the original question]. A also added some code for more complicated examples.

Answer (score 3):

A short code with `pstricks`. I define the first `=`sign in each row as nodes, and I join them with the `\ncbox` node connection, with the relevant parameters:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} %% for pdflatex compilation

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{1}
\begin{postscript}
\begin{align}
A& \mathrel{\Rnode{beg}{=}}B=C\label{a}\\
D & \mathrel{\Rnode{end}{=}}E=F\label{b}
\end{align}
\ncbox[boxsize=0.57, nodesepA=1.5ex, nodesepB=0.8ex, linecolor=IndianRed]{beg}{end}
\end{postscript}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: such a great answer by using PSTricks...