# TikZ arrows do not draw with pdflatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, pdftex, arrows

I am using the answer from [Arrow between parts of equation in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34452/arrow-between-parts-of-equation-in-latex).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}
\[
  P(x)=3x^6+4x^5\tikzmark{a}+3x^3\tikzmark{b}-x-3
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,out=315,in=225,distance=0.4cm]
    \draw[->,red,shorten >=3pt,shorten <=3pt] (a.center) to (b.center);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

This correctly draws an arrow when I compile it with `latex` then `dvipdf`, but
for some reason the arrowhead does not appear when I compile with `pdflatex`.

`latex -version` and `pdflatex -version` both output:

```
pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
kpathsea version 5.0.0
Copyright 2009 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.2.46; using libpng 1.2.46
Compiled with zlib 1.2.3.4; using zlib 1.2.3.4
Compiled with poppler version 0.18.2
```

I am also wondering what the 3.1415626 is doing there...

Comment: 3.1415626 is the version number of TeX. Each new version adds a digit of pi. Since all veresions are only bug fixes, when TeX will reach version pi, it will be bug-free.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I don't have a TeX Live 2009 at hand, but with the current version the arrow appears correctly. A tip: *never* use `$$` with LaTeX, in that case `\[...\]` should be used.

Comment: Thanks, updated answer. Any clue at all why it works with `latex` and `dvipdf` but not with `pdflatex`?

Comment: Try using `\coordinate` instead of `\node` in `\tikzmark`'s definition. Also remove `.center` when using those points.

Comment: Same result, no arrowhead with `pdflatex`.

Comment: After some more testing, I've found that replacing `->` with `-latex` or `-stealth` seems to work fine. I suppose that that will work for now...

Comment: I wonder if you're using an old version of `texlive`, have a look at [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092)

Comment: @cmhughes As it says above, it's version 2009/Debian, which is apparently what is in the Ubuntu 12.04 repositories. I will look into updating, but since I have a functional solution, I'm not really that interested in spending time on it right now.