# How to draw arrows between circled coefficients of polynomials using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikzmark

After reading Gonzalo's answer to [Arrow between parts of equation in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34452/arrow-between-parts-of-equation-in-latex), I thought  I would be able to modify it so that I could have the corresponding coefficients circled and an arrow going from one circle to the next. For example, I would like the coefficient of x^2 on the left, a, circled and the coefficient of x^2 on the right, 5 circled, then a curved arrow drawn between the two circles. How might I achieve this? Also, how would I add some text along the path of the arrow? I reproduce his code here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  a\tikzmark{a}x^2 + bx + c = 5\tikzmark{b}x^2 + bx + c.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,out=315,in=225,distance=0.4cm]
    \draw[->,red,shorten >=3pt,shorten <=3pt] (a.center) to (b.center);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Edit** Sorry, I misread the question and thought that you wanted to circle the exponents. Modifying my first solution you can circle the coefficients with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=-2pt]
    \node[circle,red,draw,text=black,anchor=center,inner sep=1pt] (#1) {$#2$};}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \tikzmark{a}{a}x^2 + bx + c = \tikzmark{b}{5}x^{2} + bx + c.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,
         decoration={text along path,text color=red, text align=center,
         raise=2pt, text={|\scriptsize|match coefficients}}]
     \draw[->,red] (a) to [out=35,in=145](b);
     \draw[decorate] (a) to [out=35,in=145](b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The use of `baseline` is presumably necessary because the circles contribute to the baseline, but this is a bit of a fudge.

The tikz library `decorations.txt` is needed to get the text to follow the curve.
This gives:

[image]

My original solution circled the exponents:

[image]

The circles are more cramped than I would like. This used a small variation on the above:

```
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[circle,red,draw,text=black,
          inner sep=0pt] (#1) {\scriptsize$#2$};}

\begin{equation}
  ax^{\tikzmark{a}{2}} + bx + c = 5x^{\tikzmark{b}{2}} + bx + c.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,
        decoration={text along path,text color=red, text align=center, 
        raise=2pt, text={|\scriptsize|match exponents}}]
     \draw[->,red] (a) to [out=25,in=155](b);
     \draw[decorate] (a) to [out=25,in=155](b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
```

Notice that I had to change the angles that the red line leaves and enters the circles in the two examples because if I had used the angles 25 and 155 for the coefficients then the red line goes through the exponents.

Answer (score 9):

You have to remove the option `overlay` from `\tikzmark` definition first. And second, alter the definition to take the same argument as label and content. Also, if you want circles to have same radius, fix some value for `minimum width` key. With these it becomes,

```
\newcommand{\mathtikzmark}[1]{\tikz[baseline={(#1.base)},remember picture] \node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.5pt,minimum width=3ex] (#1) {$#1$};}
```

I have named it `\mathtikzmark` since the contents will be in math mode (note $#1$ inside the content).

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\mathtikzmark}[1]{\tikz[baseline={(#1.base)},remember picture] \node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.5pt,minimum width=3ex] (#1) {$#1$};}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \mathtikzmark{a} x^2 + bx + c = \mathtikzmark{99} x^2 + bx + c.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,distance=0.4cm]
    \draw[->,red,in=225,out=315] (a) to (99);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want correct math spacing and don't mind if the circles overlap the adjacent parameter, here is one way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mathtikzmark}[1]{\tikz[remember picture] \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (#1) {$#1$};}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \mathtikzmark{a}x^2 + bx + c = \mathtikzmark{99}x^2 + bx + c.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[draw,circle,minimum width=1.8ex]  (n1) at (a.center) {};
    \node[draw,circle,minimum width=3ex]  (n2) at (99.center) {};
    \draw[->,red,in=225,out=315] (n1) to (n2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the `minimum width` for nodes `n1` and `n1` as you like.