# Circle two terms in an equation linking them by an arrow

Tags: equations, circles

[image: Equation]

I'd like to know if it's possible to do something like that in an equation using beamer

Comment: Yes it is. ;) You should be a little more specific.

Comment: Search for tikzmark

Answer (score 6):

It's easy to do with `pstricks`: just use the commands `\circlenode` and join them  by an arc node connection, inside the `psmatrix` environment:

```
\documentclass[x11names]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{psmatrix}
\psset{linewidth=0.5pt, linecolor=Coral1,arrows=<->, arrowinset=0.15, arcangle=45, shortput=nab, labelsep=2pt}
 x = \circlenode{A}{a} + b + \circlenode{C}{c}
\ncarc[linewidth = 0.2pt, linecolor=black]{A}{C}^{\scriptstyle=}
\end{psmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

`auto-pst-pdf` must be loaded *after* `pstricks`, and `pdflatex` must be launched with the `--enable-write18` switch (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX). To illustrate this, here is a screenshot of TeXmaker configuration:

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. I've tried my best to make this work but my latex editor accuse the following error:

Package auto-pst-pdf Error:
"shell escape" (or "write18") is not enabled:
auto-pst-pdf will not work!

Is there something I can do to fix it? I'm looking forward to here from you again. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @h3r0n3dU: Yes, I should have explained that point: either you follow the way latex->dvips->pstopdf, which is longer, or you compile with pdflatex and the switch `pdflatex -shell-escape` if you're underTeX Live or MacTeX, `--enable-write18` under MiKTeX. Alternatively, you can compile with `xelatex`. The switches can be set from within your editor, usually.

Comment: Hi @Bernard, thank you again. I'm using Texmaker on Windows 10. I followed the steps provided in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236648/92090
The editor shows a lot of warning messages, but no errors. However it doesn't work, actually the equation didn't appear in the presentation, in spite of there are no errors. Sorry, but I'm new with the LaTeX tool, so maybe I should try another alternatives. Is there something more that I can do?

Comment: Did you compile the  file I posted, exactly as it is? Also, what  is your distribution? What you can do is trying to compile from the command line, to see if it works and what are the messages.

Answer (score 1):

This can be quite easily done using the tried and tested `tikzmark` idea, demonstrated throughout this site, for example [How to draw arrows between circled coefficients of polynomials using tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196958/how-to-draw-arrows-between-circled-coefficients-of-polynomials-using-tikz) and [How to draw arrows between parts of an equation to show the Math Distributive Property (Multiplication)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35717/how-to-draw-arrows-between-parts-of-an-equation-to-show-the-math-distributive-pr)

Here's the output:

[image: screenshot]

and the code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

% tikzmark command
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]
    \node[circle,red,draw,text=black,anchor=center,inner sep=1pt] (#1) {#2};}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

    \[
        x =  \tikzmark{a}{a}+b+\tikzmark{c}{c}
    \]

    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[blue,thick,->] (a.north) to [bend left=45] node[anchor=south]{$=$}(c.north);}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```