# Tikz arrows/node not displaying properly with Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, arrows, nodes

Working on a presentation where I need to have explanations pointing to parts of an equation with an arrow. 
Tried copy-pasting the following 2 examples:
https://texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/ 
[How to draw good arrows explaining parts of equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278718/how-to-draw-good-arrows-explaining-parts-of-equation) (the solution provided by jonalv to his own question).

Here is how they are displaying in my slides individually:

[image: beamer-arrows]

[image]

It seems all the arrows are pointing/coming out of a single node instead of several. Can someone explain why that is?

Here is my settings file:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={unicode=true}]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tempora} % this supports Cyrillic
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{comment}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usepackage [section]{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
\usepackage{epsfig} % for postscript graphics files
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amsfonts}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{bm} % for bold math, improved
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}  % adds \mathscr for nice capital letters

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[baseline,remember picture] \coordinate (#1) {};}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\sign}{\operatorname{sgn}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\homd}{\lceil}{\rfloor}
\newcommand{\R}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
\newcommand\Ccancel[2][black]{\renewcommand\CancelColor{\color{#1}}\cancel{#2}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\graphicspath{{Figs/}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{my theme}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.9\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}Управление по выходу параметрическим неопределенным нелинейным объектом с нарушением условий согласования
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}{}\hspace*{2em}
        \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}

\graphicspath{{Figs/}{../Figs/}}
\usepackage{subfiles}

% ------------------- PRESENTATION INFO ---------------------------
\title{ИТЕРАТИВНАЯ ПРОЦЕДУРА СИНТЕЗА АДАПТИВНОГО УПРАВЛЕНИЯ НА БАЗЕ ИНТЕГРАЛЬНОГО АЛГОРИТМА АДАПТАЦИИ}

\date{}
\author[Олег Суздалев, R3435]{\large{\textbf{Докладчик: Суздалев Олег Димитрий}\\
Научный руководитель: Герасимов Д.Н., к.т.н.\\}}

\institute{\large{\centering\\ Университет ИТМО \\ Факультет СУиР \vspace{1em} }}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the uploaded code is not complete

Comment: @jsbibra This is just the settings file. The code used to produce those slides is exactly copy-pasted from the links I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I use only the second example you were talking about.  I
modified the command `\tikzmark` (mainly replacing `\coordinate` with `\node` which is more natural in the context) and cleaned the code slightly.

The whole code is pasted below.  The first part is your preamble that I didn't touch.  My modifications start after the line of percentages.

```
\documentclass[hyperref={unicode=true}]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tempora} % this supports Cyrillic
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{comment}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usepackage [section]{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
\usepackage{epsfig} % for postscript graphics files
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amsfonts}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{bm} % for bold math, improved
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}  % adds \mathscr for nice capital letters


\usepackage{tabularx}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\sign}{\operatorname{sgn}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\homd}{\lceil}{\rfloor}
\newcommand{\R}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
\newcommand\Ccancel[2][black]{\renewcommand\CancelColor{\color{#1}}\cancel{#2}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\graphicspath{{Figs/}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{my theme}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.9\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}Управление по выходу параметрическим неопределенным нелинейным объектом с нарушением условий согласования
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}{}\hspace*{2em}
        \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
}
\makeatother


\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}

\graphicspath{{Figs/}{../Figs/}}
\usepackage{subfiles}


% ------------------- PRESENTATION INFO ---------------------------
\title{ИТЕРАТИВНАЯ ПРОЦЕДУРА СИНТЕЗА АДАПТИВНОГО УПРАВЛЕНИЯ НА БАЗЕ ИНТЕГРАЛЬНОГО АЛГОРИТМА АДАПТАЦИИ}

\date{}
\author[Олег Суздалев, R3435]{\large{\textbf{Докладчик: Суздалев Олег Димитрий}\\
Научный руководитель: Герасимов Д.Н., к.т.н.\\}}

\institute{\large{\centering\\ Университет ИТМО \\ Факультет СУиР \vspace{1em} }}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=.5ex] (#1) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Tests}

  This is the example ``How to draw good arrows explaining parts of
  equation?'' you were pointing to in the question.

  \vfill
  
  \hspace{4em}
  $\tikzmark{V}V
  = \tikzmark{Vp}V_p
  + \tikzmark{Vt}V_t\,\frac{fu\tikzmark{fu}}{fu_t\tikzmark{fut}}$

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,
    every node/.style={scale=.7, inner sep=3pt},
    spear/.style={->, blue, shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt}]
      
    \node
    (Ve) [below of=V, node distance=10em, anchor=west]
    {\textsf{distribution volume}};
    \node (Vpe) [below of=Vp, node distance=7em, anchor=west]
    {\textsf{volume water in plasma}};
    \node (Vte) [below of=Vt, node distance=4em, anchor=west]
    {\textsf{volume water in tissue}};
    \node (fue) [above right of=fu, node distance=4em, anchor=west]
    {\textsf{fraction unbound drug in plasma}};
    \node (fute) [right of=fut, node distance=4em, anchor=west]
    {\textsf{Fraction unbound drug in tissue}};
    
    \draw
    (Ve) edge[spear, out=175, in=-115] (V)
    (Vpe) edge[spear, out=180, in=-110] (Vp)
    (Vte) edge[spear, out=180, in=-105] (Vt)
    (fue) edge[spear, out=182, in=40] (fu)
    (fute) edge[spear, out=180, in=-20] (fut);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```