# curved arrows with tikz package

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am trying to make, with tikz package, curved arrows like this:
[image]

Can somebody help me?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196958/how-to-draw-arrows-between-circled-coefficients-of-polynomials-using-tikz/196962#196962

Comment: Did Andrew's link solve your problem?

Comment: Of course, with a little intercession of mine, I achieved what I wanted, thanks to his help.