# How to make this kind of arrows on Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

[image]

Also, how to center tikz pictures? I did what I wanted with curved arrows like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric,arrows}

\begin{document}

\[ \tau\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (1){};\  \vee\neg\in\square\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (2){};\ A^\prime\in\square\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (3){};\ A^{\prime\prime} \] 

            \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm, auto, text centered, overlay, remember picture]
            \draw[->,>=stealth,bend left=60,shorten <= .2cm,shorten >= .2cm] (1.north) to (2.north);
            \draw[->,>=stealth,bend left=60,shorten <= .2cm,shorten >= .2cm] (1.north) to (3.north);
            \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And I tried a lot of things to get it centered, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: You should divide this question to 2 different questions.

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Related:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196958/how-to-draw-arrows-between-circled-coefficients-of-polynomials-using-tikz/196962#196962

Comment: The [overlay] options does just that.  In fact, it turns off the bounding box so you can't even figure out how big it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost this exact example is also to be found in the manual of `chemmacros`.  Hence I suggest you use this package.  Here is the example, slightly adapted to your use-case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{redox}
\chemsetup[redox]{explicit-sign=true}
\begin{document}

\ch{
  2 "\OX{o1,\ox*{0,Na}}" + "\OX{r1,\ox*{0,Cl}}" {}2
  ->
  2 "\OX{o2,\ox*{+1,Na}}" {}+ + 2 "\OX{r2,\ox*{-1,Cl}}" {}-
}
\redox(o1,o2)[->]{\small oxidation}
\redox(r1,r2)[->][-1]{\small reduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]