# Line in equations

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations

How would you write the code for this expression?:

[image]

Comment: You can use the `tikzmark` library of `tikz`.

Comment: I have added a very similar question. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278718

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34452

Answer (score 4):

**I have added some examples - they are not perfect but a start.**

```
% Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34452 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35717
% Remark: Please compile at least 2 times (otherwise the arrow position may be wrong).

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  a\tikzmark{a_mark}x^2 + bx + c = 5\tikzmark{b_mark}x^2 + bx + c.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    overlay,
    remember picture,
    out = 315, % degree
    in = 225, % degree
    distance = 5mm,
    ]
    \draw[
        ->,
        red,
        ] (a_mark.center) to (b_mark.center);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  a\tikzmark{a_mark}x^2 + bx + c = 5\tikzmark{b_mark}x^2 + bx + c.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    overlay,
    remember picture,
    out = 45, % degree
    in = 135, % degree
    distance = 10mm,
    ]
    \draw[
        ->,
        blue,
        ] (a_mark.center) to (b_mark.center);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  a\tikzmark{a_mark}x^2 + bx + c = 5\tikzmark{b_mark}x^2 + bx + c.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    overlay,
    remember picture,
    out = 45, % degree
    in = 135, % degree
    distance = 10mm,
    ]
    \draw[
        ->,
        green,
        shorten > = 15pt,
        shorten < = 15pt,
        ] (a_mark.center) to (b_mark.center);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or using `tikzmark`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\[ f(0) = \tikzmarknode{1}{1}
\foreach \X in {2,3,4}
{\;,\quad f(\the\numexpr\X-1)= \tikzmarknode{\X}{\the\numexpr2*\X-1}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {2,3,4}
  {\draw[-{Stealth[bend]},red!80!black] (\Y.north east) 
  to[bend left] node[above]{$+2$}
  (\X.north west);}
\end{tikzpicture}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but is different.

Comment: @ArnoldFernández As you can see from your negative vote (it wasn't me), your question is maybe not ideal. I strongly suggest, that you read the following link carefully and try to follow the recommendations: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228. Asking a "good question" is hard work and takes time!

Comment: I hope you do not mind the edit but my really think one should not define `\tikzmark`, which is a command of the `tikzmark` library. Rather, please use the `tikzmark` library and, in particular, `\tikzmarknode`.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat Thanks! I apparently used a very old question as a template before the library was available.

Answer (score 3):

A short code with `pstricks`: each value is made an `\rnode`, and these nodes are linked by a node connection with the relevant shape (`\ncarc`) with a label above:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

    \[ f(0) = \rnode{1}{1},\; f(1)= \rnode{2}{3},\; f(2)= \rnode{3}{5},\; f(3)= \rnode{4}{7}
    \psset{linewidth = 0.5pt, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.15, arcangle=45, labelsep=1pt, nodesep=1pt, linecolor=IndianRed}
    \foreach \s/\t in{1/2,2/3,3/4}{\ncarc[offset=2pt]{\s}{\t}\naput{\color{IndianRed}\medmath{+2}}}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How would it be with Tikz?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm no expert in TiKZ. It certainly is also possible, but probably with a bit longer code. Certainly some of the Tikz specialists will propose a code.

Comment: @ArnoldFernández No, the code is *not* longer with Ti*k*Z. The converse is true. (I have been using PSTricks for more over a decade and find it not appropriate to claim that the code with Ti*k*Z is *longer* than with PSTricks. In 90% of the cases it is precisely the opposite.)

Comment: Bernard, how is it possible that, on the one hand, by your own admission you are "no expert on Ti*k*Z", but on the other hand you think that the code will be longer? As someone who has used PSTricks over a long time I can tell you that there is absolutely no basis for such claims, and this very example is substantiating the empirical fact that PSTricks is usually longer and, to me more importantly, far less flexible, even if one ignores the fact that you are very restricted in the choice of compilers. The only reason why your code is not excessively long is that you load `pgffor`.

Comment: Don't fight :). You're both great :).