# A \boxed alternative with nicer spacing?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, boxes

I like using `\boxed` to emphasize my answers in homework problem sets. However, whenever I use superscripts/exponents inside the box, the box becomes taller than it seems it should. This causes two problems: the box looks bad, and it pushes other lines of text around.

Here's an example. Notice that the line spacing doesn't get changed until I use an exponent inside a box.

[image]

Is there an alternative to `\boxed` that won't have this problem? Or some other good way to solve this issue?

Comment: If you use `\myboxed{...}` instead of `\boxed{...}` where `\newcommand{\myboxed}[1]{\smash{\boxed{#1}}}`, then you can decide whether a removal of the boxing height works for you or not. `\smash` puts its contents in a box of height zero.

Comment: Are you concerned with the horizontal or vertical spacing, or both?

Comment: I had the exact same problem recently. My solution was to put my answers in a different color. If that's not available to you, I think Werner's subtle shaded background box is also a nice solution. Both highlight what you want to highlight in an unobtrusive, easily understood, and typographically non-ugly way.

Comment: Related Question: [mdframed: size frame to content](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88634/mdframed-size-frame-to-content).

Answer (score 12):

You can use `tikzmark` as from [this answer by Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570) to mark the endpoints where you want the box.  The `\MyBox` macro as defined below accepts an optional first parameter which allows you to get fancy boxes.

[image]

### Notes:

- This does require two runs: the first to compute the positions of the box, and the second to draw it in the correct spot.

### Known Issues:

- This won't work if the text crosses line boundaries. If this is an issue and you are willing to consider highlighting instead of a box you should refer to [Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex).
- This version will not adjust properly for text that adjusts the vertical spacing (ex. `\dfrac{1}{2}` from the `amsmath` package).  However, an updated version of this that adjusts to the correct height is provided at [A \boxed alternative with minimal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35319/a-boxed-alternative-with-minimal-spacing/35357#35357)

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[1][red]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \draw[#1]
      ($(bl)+(-0.2em,0.9em)$) rectangle
      ($(br)+(0.2em,-0.3em)$);}
}
\newcommand{\MyBox}[2][red]{\tikzmark{bl}#2\tikzmark{br}\DrawBox[#1]}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \MyBox{Lorem ipsum} dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Lorem 
    ipsum \MyBox[blue]{$3.29 \times 10^{29}$} dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem 
    ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem 
    \MyBox[draw=red,fill=yellow!20,,opacity=0.3]{$3.29 \times 10^{29}$} ipsum dolor sit amet. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to automate the size. more precisely, the solution does not work with fractions for example.

Comment: @projetmbc: Yep, that is a known issue with this solution as I highlighted in the _Known Issues_ section, but in this case the OP specifically was interested in using it in cases where the enclosed text did not effect the line inter line spacing. I to would be interested in that so perhaps post a follow up question if you can't find the solution here already,

Comment: I've posted my "hope" here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35319/a-boxed-alternative-with-minimal-spacing .

Comment: @projetmbc: An updated `tikz` solution that adjusts for the vertical size of the text being enclosed has been posted at [a boxed alternative with minimal spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35319/a-boxed-alternative-with-minimal-spacing/35357#35357).

Answer (score 8):

If you're interested in duplicating the behaviour of `\boxed` when it comes to the appearance, but remove the height-associated addition (supplied by `\fboxrule` and `\fboxsep`), you could define your own boxing macro based on `\boxed`. This is what `\boxed` is defined as in [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

```
\newcommand{\boxed}[1]{\fbox{\m@th$\displaystyle#1$}}
```

As such, defining `\myboxed` to be

```
\newcommand{\myboxed}[1]{%
  \rlap{\hspace*{\dimexpr\fboxrule+\fboxsep\relax}%
    \phantom{\m@th$\displaystyle#1$}}%
    \smash{\boxed{#1}}}
```

would achieve this. Here is an MWE showing the resulting output for two paragraphs; the first uses `\boxed`, while the second uses `\myboxed`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myboxed}[1]{%
  \rlap{\hspace*{\dimexpr\fboxrule+\fboxsep\relax}%
    \phantom{\m@th$\displaystyle#1$}}%
    \smash{\boxed{#1}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ligula dui, blandit et posuere eu, varius in erat. 
Nunc ornare tellus in dui \boxed{3.299\times 10^{29}} tempus facilisis. Nunc ornare tellus 
in dui tempus facilisis. \boxed{3.299} Nulla vel dolor augue. Nulla commodo nulla et tortor 
aliquam nec lacinia odio sagittis. Aenean vitae interdum dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. $3.299\times 10^{29}$ Aliquam ligula dui, blandit et posuere 
eu, varius in erat. Nunc ornare tellus in dui tempus facilisis.


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ligula dui, blandit et posuere eu, varius in erat. 
Nunc ornare tellus in dui \myboxed{3.299\times 10^{29}} tempus facilisis. Nunc ornare 
tellus in dui tempus facilisis. \myboxed{3.299} Nulla vel dolor augue. Nulla commodo nulla 
et tortor aliquam nec lacinia odio sagittis. Aenean vitae interdum dui. Lorem ipsum dolor 
sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. $3.299\times 10^{29}$ Aliquam ligula dui, blandit et 
posuere eu, varius in erat. Nunc ornare tellus in dui tempus facilisis.

\end{document}
```

You'll note that it also highlights some of the problems with removing the vertical boxing adjustment. @Boris' suggestion to reduce `\fboxsep` would help. You could also print something more subtle like a shaded box and remove the solid rule. Here's an alternative to `\myboxed` that achieves that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myboxed}[2][black!5]{%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt} \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
  \rlap{\hspace*{\fboxsep}%
    \phantom{\m@th$\displaystyle#2$}}%
    \smash{\colorbox{#1}{\m@th$\displaystyle#2$}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ligula dui, blandit et posuere eu, varius in erat. 
Nunc ornare tellus in dui \boxed{3.299\times 10^{29}} tempus facilisis. Nunc ornare tellus 
in dui tempus facilisis. \boxed{3.299} Nulla vel dolor augue. Nulla commodo nulla et tortor 
aliquam nec lacinia odio sagittis. Aenean vitae interdum dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. $3.299\times 10^{29}$ Aliquam ligula dui, blandit et posuere 
eu, varius in erat. Nunc ornare tellus in dui tempus facilisis.


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ligula dui, blandit et posuere eu, varius in erat. 
Nunc ornare tellus in dui \myboxed{3.299\times 10^{29}} tempus facilisis. Nunc ornare 
tellus in dui tempus facilisis. \myboxed{3.299} Nulla vel dolor augue. Nulla commodo nulla 
et tortor aliquam nec lacinia odio sagittis. Aenean vitae interdum dui. Lorem ipsum dolor 
sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. $3.299\times 10^{29}$ Aliquam ligula dui, blandit et 
posuere eu, varius in erat. Nunc ornare tellus in dui tempus facilisis.

\end{document}
```

`\myboxed` has been fitted with an optional argument to modify the colour (default is `black!5` or 5% black):

```
\myboxed[<colour>]{<stuff>}
```

Answer (score 7):

Change the two values for the depth and the height to whatever you need:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newsavebox\FBox
\def\Boxed#1{\sbox\FBox{%\fboxsep=1.5pt% may also be useful
   $\boxed{#1}$}\rule[-1.2\dp\FBox]{0pt}{1.2\ht\FBox}\usebox\FBox}
\begin{document}

This is some long text This is some long text 
This is some long text This is some long text 
\Boxed{3.299\times10^{29}} This is some long text 
This is some long text This is some long text This is some long text 
This is some long text This is some \Boxed{3.299} long text 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be using a `tcbox` from `tcolorbox` package. Recent (v 3.05) `tcolorbox` versions offer `size` option which easily fixes some default box characteristics (size, corners, border width, ...). Its `size=tight` definition could be too tight but with help of `boxsep=1pt` the result is good to my taste.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\MyBox}[1][red]{on line, size=tight, boxsep=1pt, colframe=#1!50!black, colback=#1!10!white}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \MyBox{Lorem ipsum} dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Lorem 
    ipsum \MyBox[blue]{$3.29 \times 10^{29}$} dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem 
    ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem 
    \MyBox[green]{$3.29 \times 10^{29}$} ipsum dolor sit amet. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

Decrease the separation between the box and the text:

```
\setlength\fboxsep{1pt}
\lipsum*[1]$\boxed{10^x}$\lipsum[2]
```

**Solution 2**

Decrease the size of the boxed formula:

```
\lipsum*[1]$\footnotesize\boxed{10^x}$\lipsum[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution that I came up with today that solves the original question, but also satisfies the *additional requirement* that all boxes are the same height.

```
\usepackage[customcolors,nofill,norndcorners]{hf-tikz}
\hfsetbordercolor{black}

\newcounter{boxCounter}
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{
    \stepcounter{boxCounter}
    \hspace{0.3em}
    \tikzmarkin[thin,left offset=-0.15em,right offset=0.15em,below offset=-0.35em,above offset=0.9em]{\theboxCounter}#1\tikzmarkend{\theboxCounter}
    \hspace{0.3em}
}
```

For example, `$\boxed{c}$` and `$\boxed{f(c)}$` on the same line would result in boxes of different heights and additionally affects the interline spacing.

Using my solution, the boxes (i.e. `$\mybox{c}$` and `$\mybox{f(c)}$`) are much tighter around the content, are the same height, and the interline spacing is unaffected (i.e. it remains as if no boxes were drawn).

Two caveats:

- You may have to adjust the above and below offset in the `\mybox` command to suit your font, etc.
- This solution will not adjust properly for text that adjusts the vertical spacing (e.g. `\dfrac{1}{2}` from the `amsmath` package), however, this is a side affect of the requirement that all boxes be the same height on a page.

Thus while it avoids the need for `vphantom`'s in multiple boxes, it may not suit your needs. However, it could be adapted to handle content which does adjust the vertical spacing.

Comment: Please _always_ post a complete compilable example including `\documentclass`.  If you want one that adjusts to various heights, see [A \boxed alternative with minimal spacing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35319/a-boxed-alternative-with-minimal-spacing/35357#35357).