# Drawing boxes around words

Tags: boxes

I want to put some small boxes around certain words in a paragraph. The boxes will never contain more than one word.

The `\ovalbox` command described in the `fancybox` documentation is close to what I need. However, I found some problems:

- The rounded corners do not line up with the sides perfectly.
- Text to the left and right in the paragraph are pushed away.
- The spacing between lines in the paragraph is increased vertically.

I would like to create boxes which:

- Adjust horizontally to fit the width of the text inside.
- Have rounded or beveled corners.
- Can be filled with a solid color.
- Will not cause any text inside or around the box to move.
- Will not impact the vertical spacing of lines.

Comment: You can use `PSTricks` or `TikZ`.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [a boxed alternative with minimal spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35319/a-boxed-alternative-with-minimal-spacing)

Comment: I agree with @peter. I think that the answer from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35346/9390 can be modified to include the proper spacings from the fancybox package to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `TikZ` with the `overlay` option and a correct anchor. That would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\mybox[2][]{\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=blue!20,inner sep=2pt, anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,#1] {#2};\phantom{#2}}
\begin{document}
   \noindent
   this is some text \mybox[fill=blue!20]{box} text\\
   this is some text box text
\end{document}
```

You can specify extra options (like I have done here for the color). By using the `overlay` option and the `text` anchor we ensure correct placement and no influence on spacing. The `phantom` is added to get the normal spacing for the content of the box. This is the result of the example code:

[image: TikZ text box]

**Edit:** To show that the vertical spacing is not affected either, consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\mybox[2][]{\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=blue!20,inner sep=2pt, anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,#1] {#2};\phantom{#2}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \noindent
    this is some text \mybox[fill=blue!20]{box} text\\
    this is some text box text
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \noindent
    this is some text box text\\
    this is some text box text
  \end{minipage}    
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image: TikZ text box vertical spacing]

Comment: `\def\mybox[#1]#2` would force the "optional" argument, so `\newcommand\mybox[2][]` would be better.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: You are absolutely correct. I have modified the answer to reflect this. The `[fill=blue!20]` is now of course also optional on the `\mybox` command.

Comment: @wh1t3 And what happens if the boxed word is at the end of line with some cesura ? I think you have a vertically  problem and some text are pushed horizontally !

Comment: You can try : `  \begin{minipage}{4cm}
    \noindent
    this is  a word boxed  \mybox[fill=blue!20]{problem}.
  \end{minipage}  `

Comment: Another problem appears if `inner sep` is too greater. The box can erase some parts of character like `p`or if two boxed word are one above the other. In a normal case, you can remove `inner sep=2pt` and `rectangle` because these values are given by default. I think it's very difficult to keep a text very clean (in terms of typography) when  some words are boxed.

Comment: @Altermundus: You are right in concluding that the boxing breaks hyphenation. I don't see a nice way around this though and I don't think the OP was expecting this. I don't know exactly what you mean with your last comment. The OP simply shouldn't make `inner sep` much larger, since it will start to overlap with preceding and succeeding words. Again, this is by design, the OP clearly states he does not want horizontal or vertical spacing to be affected. I can't fit a huge box in a tiny gap. `rectangle` is default, I believe `inner sep` is greater than `2pt` by default though.

Comment: the vertical spacing _is_ affected. Try it with a contents like "fg"

Comment: @Herbert: With vertical spacing I was referring to the vertical space between lines as the OP mentions. The vertical *size* of the box is indeed dependent on what is inside. If this is unwanted you could add `text depth=0pt` as an option to the node. This does not fix it entirely though. There are multiple options, the easiest is to set `text height=1.5ex`. This way you will have uniform box height.

Comment: @RoelofSpijker Thanks for your answer. If I had `\usepackage[french]{babel}` it is not working anymore!!! error : `Runaway argument?
\node [fill=blue!20,inner sep=2pt, anchor=text, rectangle, rounded co\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \tikz@next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> test.tex`

Comment: Solved by adding after `\usepackage{tike}` the following : `\tikzset{
    every picture/.prefix style={
        execute at begin picture=\shorthandoff{;}
    }
}`

Comment: Can you explain again what the phantom is used for? Thanks. Great answer!

Comment: Like it says in the answer: "The phantom is added to get the normal spacing for the content of the box". Basically, because the node is placed in 'overlay mode', it has 0 size when being placed. But we don't want the next word to overlap, so we add a phantom to take up the space that the word would normally take up without actually printing the word. Try removing the phantom and see what happens. (It's been a while since I used any of this, just saw your comment. So I'm really hoping this is actually true... Pretty sure it is :))

Comment: @RoelofSpijker , could you please explain to me what is the role of `#1` ?

Comment: @MedVall, the `#1` takes the value of the optional arguments. In the example I use `fill=blue!20`, which is superfluous because I already set it in the node command. Anyway, this value for `#1` is added in the optional part of the `node` command. So you can give it a set of comma-separated arguments that the `node` command understands.

Answer (score 12):

My solution needs no special macros. No TikZ, no PSTricks. Only `\pdfliteral` primitive is used. And you can define `\def\pdfliteral#1{\special{pdf:literal #1}}` if `\pdfliteral` isn't available (for example in XeTeX).

```
\def\mybox#1{\leavevmode \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
   \dimen0=\wd0 \edef\posxA{\expandafter\ignorept\the\dimen0 \space}%
   \hbox{\kern3pt\pdfliteral{q .8 .8 1 rg .8 .8 1 RG .9963 0 0 .9963 0 0 cm 1 j 1 J 6 w
                             0 0 m 0 5 l \posxA 5 l \posxA 0 l 0 0 l B Q}%
         \box0 \kern3pt}%
}
{\lccode`\?=`\p \lccode`\!=`\t  \lowercase{\gdef\ignorept#1?!{#1}}}

This is a \mybox{test} of my \mybox{box}.

\bye
```

[image: roundbox]

Comment: Where/How do you define the colors? For example, what would be the settings for light gray?

Comment: The color is defined in RGB color model in my example: 0.8 red, 0.8 green, 1 blue. For fills (rg) and the same for strokes (RG), see ".8 .8 1 rg .8 .8 1 RG". If you want light gray, then you can use GRAY color model (g for fills, G for strokes), for example ".9 g .9 G".

Comment: Cool! thank you!

Answer (score 10):

This kind of boxes can be done with `extrude` option from `tcolorbox`. A little example adapted from `tcolorbox` documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{enhanced, colframe=blue, colback=blue!15, 
       frame style={opacity=0.25}, interior style={opacity=0.25}, 
       nobeforeafter, tcbox raise base, shrink tight, extrude by=1mm, #1}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Ut \mybox[extrude bottom by=2cm]{purus} elit, vestibulum ut, \mybox{placerat} ac, 
\mybox[extrude top by=2mm]{adipiscing} vitae, \mybox[extrude left by=5mm, extrude 
bottom by=2mm]{felis}. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. \mybox{Nam} arcu libero,    
nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Basically similar to the solution given by Roelof Spijker. I suggest handling the optional argument differently, and use a `\strut` to ensure consistent box size while not changing the line spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\mmybox[2][fill=blue!20]{%
    \tikz[baseline]\node[%
        inner ysep=0pt, 
        inner xsep=2pt, 
        anchor=text, 
        rectangle, 
        rounded corners=1mm,
        #1] {\strut#2};%
}

\begin{document}
   \noindent
   this is some text \mmybox{Box} text\\
   this is some text box text
\end{document}
```

The results:

[image: Sample of boxed text]