# Customize stackoverflow like source code box using tcolorbox extrude, with constant space around word

Tags: fonts, footnotes, tcolorbox

I try to change font familly in my `tcolorbox` to have similar font than the font for `source code in stackoverflow`, without success.

The height of line is also not correct, there is a difference between line with box and line without box, is there a way to define automatically the correct height of the box to eliminate this effect ?

[image]

The code for box is

```
   \makeatletter
    \newtcbox{\keywordmin}{on line, fontupper=\scriptsize\texttt, boxrule=0.5pt,arc=2pt,coltext=tangoBlack1,colback=tangoGrey1,colframe=tangoGrey1,boxsep=0pt,left=2pt,right=2pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt}
    \makeatother
```

Here the complete MWE

```
% !TEX encoding =  UTF-8 Unicode
% -*- program: xelatex -*-
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{mwe} % just for dummy images
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amstext}    % defines the \text command, needed here
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 

\definecolor{tangoBlack1}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{tangoGrey1}{RGB}{136,138,133}

\usepackage{sepfootnotes}
\newfootnotes{A}

\footmarkstyle{[#1]~}
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{-1sp}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0pt}
\setlength{\footparindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\foottextfont}{\scriptsize\raggedright}

\makeatletter
\newtcbox{\keywordmin}{on line, fontupper=\scriptsize\texttt, boxrule=0.5pt,arc=2pt,coltext=tangoBlack1,colback=tangoGrey1,colframe=tangoGrey1,boxsep=0pt,left=2pt,right=2pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Anotecontent{code_note}{This is a technical note with \keywordmin{Code} tag used to describe \keywordmin{keyword} in source code. This is a technical note with \keywordmin{Code} tag used to describe \keywordmin{keyword} in source code. I want to add some blablabla on the same line..I want to add some blablabla on the same line..I want to add some blablabla on the same line..I want to add some blablabla on the same line..  I want to add some blablabla on the same line..I want to add some blablabla on the same line.. }

This is a message which need a footnotes \Anote{code_note}.

\end{document}
```

**Update 1 :**

I upgrade the question using first answer based on @harish-kumar answer and answer of this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36401/drawing-boxes-around-words) to better explain my need.

If i augment the size of extrude (like `extrude by=3pt` or `extrude by=4pt`) to construct a more fancy box, the extrud **"eat"** other word around. Is there a way with `tcolorbox` to maintain a correct space (1pt) betwen colored box and the word around ?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `shrink tight,extrude by=2pt` in this way

```
\newtcbox{\keywordmin}{on line, fontupper=\scriptsize\ttfamily, boxrule=0.5pt,arc=2pt,coltext=tangoBlack1,colback=tangoGrey1,colframe=tangoGrey1, boxsep=0pt,shrink tight,extrude by=2pt}
```

Here `shrink tight` makes the  total colored box to be shrunk to the dimensions of the upper part while `extrude by = 2pt` makes the colored box to be extruded by `2pt` to all sides. The inner width and the bounding box is kept unchanged.

Also, you should use `fontupper=\scriptsize\ttfamily` instead of `\texttt`.

Code:

```
% !TEX encoding =  UTF-8 Unicode
% -*- program: xelatex -*-
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{mwe} % just for dummy images
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amstext}    % defines the \text command, needed here
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{tangoBlack1}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{tangoGrey1}{RGB}{136,138,133}

\usepackage{sepfootnotes}
\newfootnotes{A}

\footmarkstyle{[#1]~}
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{-1sp}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0pt}
\setlength{\footparindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\foottextfont}{\scriptsize\raggedright}

\makeatletter
\newtcbox{\keywordmin}{on line, fontupper=\scriptsize\ttfamily, boxrule=0.5pt,arc=2pt,coltext=tangoBlack1,colback=tangoGrey1,colframe=tangoGrey1, boxsep=0pt,shrink tight,extrude by=2pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Anotecontent{code_note}{This is a technical note with \keywordmin{Code} tag used to describe \keywordmin{keyword} in source code. This is a technical note with \keywordmin{Code} tag used to describe \keywordmin{keyword} in source code. I want to add some blablabla on the same line..I want to add some blablabla on the same line..I want to add some blablabla on the same line..I want to add some blablabla on the same line..  I want to add some blablabla on the same line..I want to add some blablabla on the same line.. }

This is a message which need a footnotes \Anote{code_note}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thnaks for answer, is it possible to add some free space around the box, because if i extrude more (like 3pt), the box color other word around :/ ? (i update my question)

Comment: @reyman64 If you do that the spacing will be uneven as your earlier case. You have to maintain optimum space yourself. There is also `extrude left`, `extrude top` etc if you want to adjust all sides independently. Do something like `extrude top=3pt,extrude bottom=3pt,extrude right=2pt, extrude left=2pt`