# How to make this fancy highlight?

Tags: tikz-pgf, highlighting, syntax-highlighting

Nowadays websites show inline computer-code/files in a nice fancy way, with a background color, and rounded box around it, see e.g. the example below.

How can I reproduce this in Latex?

Thanks

[Link of the screenshot below.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html)

[image]

Comment: I think you might find this post helpful http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236608/customize-stackoverflow-like-source-code-box-using-tcolorbox-extrude-with-const, except for the text-colour and line around the box it seems to do what you are asking.

Comment: Would the box have to be able  to break at the end of lines?

Answer (score 6):

You can try with a `tcbox`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newtcbox{\code}[1][]{%
     size=fbox,
    tcbox raise base, nobeforeafter, 
    enhanced, colframe=gray,
    colback=gray!30, boxrule=1pt,
    fontupper=\ttfamily,
    #1}

\begin{document}

the \code{parent} section of the POM. The \code[colupper=red!70!black]{spring-boot-starter-parent} is a special \dots \code[colupper=blue!70]{dependency-management} section

\end{document}
```

[image]