# Position text next to rectangle in TikZ but allow it to wrap around

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikzpagenodes

This question builds off of the one here: [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75298/position-text-next-to-rectangle-in-tikz)

However, my question is how do I wrap around the text?

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=black!40!white,
      thick,
      draw,
      minimum height=0.5cm,
      minimum width=3.2cm,
      label=south:The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog %< -- This uses an anchor of the node for the location
] at (0,1.5) {Canonical Polyadic};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I get is this long line of text at the south of the rectangle.

[image]

I have tried specifying `text width = 3.2 cm`, etc but they don't see to me to be having any effect.

Comment: First, a label is actually another node, so basically you need two overlapping nodes, one with text and one for the rectangle.  (Well, you really don't need a node for the rectangle.)  However, wrapping text around objects is not easy.  You can use \parshape for single paragraps, but in this case I would simply manually add gaps to the text.

Comment: Thanks! So, I tried forcing a break `The quick brown fox \\ jumps over the lazy dog` but that did not do anything. What does manually adding gaps to the text mean? I did try placing as a separate node `\node[below of=check, text width = 2 cm]  {The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog};` and this seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Although you accepted my answer, I still have a doubt about the real problem. Do you want text around a box? or do you want text that contains a box in the middle? In the second case I think it's better to use a `\tcbox` like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364234/1952

Comment: Thanks, I did not want it around the box but close to the box. The suggestion made my @JohnKormylo was adequate for my immediate needs, and it is very unfortunate that we can only check one answer. Yours is a bit moe so I checked it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `label` is another node. You can fix its width independently from the labelled node and you can place as many labels as you need.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=black!40!white,
      thick,
      draw,
      minimum height=0.5cm,
      minimum width=3.2cm,
      label={[text width=3cm, align=center]south:The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog} 
] (a) {Canonical Polyadic};
\node[fill=black!40!white,
      thick,
      draw,
      minimum height=0.5cm,
      minimum width=3.2cm,
      label={north:The quick brown fox}, 
      label={west:jumps}, 
      label={east:over}, 
      label={south:the lazy dog}, 
right=3cm of a] (b) {Canonical Polyadic};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This shows how to manually wrap text inside a node.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width=4.1cm, font={\baselineskip=.5cm}] (A)
  {The quick brown fox \hspace*{3.1cm} jumps over the lazy dog};
\node[fill=black!40!white,
      thick,
      draw,
      minimum height=0.5cm,
      minimum width=3.2cm,
      right
] at (A.west) {Canonical Polyadic};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]