# Why is my \special{ps: ...} not getting the dimensions correct?

Tags: postscript

Trying things out without relying on `pstricks` to see if I can write my own postscript code embedded within a LaTeX document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hello world! 
  \special{ps:
     /inch { 72 mul } def
     gsave
     0 0 1 setrgbcolor
     1 inch 0      rlineto
     0      1 inch rlineto
    -1 inch 0      rlineto
     closepath
     4 setlinewidth
    stroke
    grestore
    }%%
Followed by something else.

\rule{1in}{4pt}

\end{document}
```

The box is placed where I expect it to be, but the dimensions are all wrong:

[image]

But I can easily write an `eps` file

```
%!PS-Adoboe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0  72 72
/inch { 72  mul } def
newpath
0 0 moveto
1 inch 0      rlineto
 0      1 inch rlineto
-1 inch 0      rlineto
closepath
stroke
showpage
```

And import it to get a square of the right size

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Hello world! 
Followed by something else.

\includegraphics{square}

\rule{1in}{4pt}

\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

So what do I need to do to get the dimensions correct within `\special{ps:....}`?

I've tried looking through `pstricks.sty`, `pstricks.tex`, and `pstricks.con` but not finding anything useful to explain why `pstricks` is able to get things right, but I'm not.

By the way, with both of the above examples I'm compiling via

```
latex --> dvips --> ps2pdf
```

Comment: PostScript is a scalable format 1 1 moveto doesn't mean move 1pt it means move by 1 unit in the current coordinate matrix

Comment: @egreg I made the code for both the embedded `\special` and `eps` file better resemble each other.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle According to my PostScript document `72` should equal an inch.  It seems to do it fine out of the box for the `eps` file, why not in the `\special`? How do I set the coordinate matrix to be what I want?

Comment: 72 only equals 1in at the start: if the line above is 2 2 scale then it means 2 in. If you use `ps:` rather than `"` as the special prefix it is inserted into the postscript that dvips is constructing so is influenced by any changes to the graphics state dvips has made (and it makes a lot)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So you're saying I need to duplicate `\pstverb` ?  Where do I read up on what the `"` does?  I noticed it, but didn't understand what purpose it served.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Defining my own equivalent of `\pstverb` did the trick.  Could you either explain the difference between `\special{"` and `\special{ps:` or point me to a reference where I could read up on it (or both).  :)

Comment: `texdoc dvips`, page 30:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `"` instead of `ps:` then `dvips` resets the graphics state before
inserting the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hello world! 
  \special{"
     /inch { 72 mul } def
     gsave
     newpath
     0 0 moveto
     0 0 1 setrgbcolor
     1 inch 0      rlineto
     0      1 inch rlineto
    -1 inch 0      rlineto
     closepath
     4 setlinewidth
    stroke
    grestore
    }%%
Followed by something else.

\rule{1in}{4pt}

\end{document}
```

with `ps:` you get whatever the current coordinate matrix is (which you can query from PostScript if you really need it)

Comment: So it would seem that the `gsave` and `grestore` are unnecessary when calling with `\special{"`.

Comment: @A.Ellett yep, using `"` is like including an eps file, there is a save restore and a graphics reset implicitly wrapped around the code. try the `\special` two forms and compare the generated ps file it's quite readable (or at least I used to read it often 20 years ago while writing the graphics package:-)