# Color Box Theorem Headtitle only

Tags: xetex, color

I want to put a colored box in every theorem, example etc. Only the headtile and not it's contents. I've found an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36401/drawing-boxes-around-words)  which works for simple tetx. But is does not work for theorems, examples etc. I get an error "Use of \simpletitleshade doesn't match its definition T". Here's my code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\simpletitleshade[#1]#2{\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=cyan,inner sep=2pt, anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,#1] {#2};\phantom{#2}}%

\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\normalfont\bfseries\simpletitleshade,postheadspace=\newline]{simpleshaded}

\declaretheorem[style=simpleshaded,numberwithin=section,name=Example]{example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
Test
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tcolorbox` includes a library for `theorems` and similar environments. An example with color boxed title could be declared with:

\documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcbtheorem{MyExample}{Example}%
{enhanced, tile, left=0pt, right=0pt, colback=white, attach boxed title to top left, boxed title style={colback=blue!30, sharp corners}, varwidth boxed title}{ex}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{MyExample}{AAA}{a}% First parameter = Title, Second = label
\lipsum[1]
\end{MyExample}

As can be seen in example~\ref{ex:a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get the following errors from your mwe.
pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tcb/attach boxed title to top left' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \begin{MyExample}{AAA}{a}
pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tcb/boxed title style' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \begin{MyExample}{AAA}{a}
pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tcb/varwidth boxed title' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \begin{MyExample}{AAA}{a}

Comment: @C.Apollon please, update tcolorbox package and try again