# How to add style to command for tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

The `mybox` command is from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36404/222091).

Original `mybox`

```
\newcommand\mybox[2][]{\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=black!20, inner sep=2pt, 
                        anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,#1] {#2};\phantom{#2}}
```

If I use this command, I get results like below

[image]

I want it to have a bit more code like style, So I made it like below

```
\newcommand\mybox[2][]{\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=black!20, inner sep=2pt, 
                        anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,\texttt{#1}] {#2};\phantom{#2}}
```

This one didn't even compile, so I searched and adjusted it to

```
\newcommand\mybox[2][]{\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=black!20,font=\ttfamily, inner sep=2pt, 
                        anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,#1] {#2};\phantom{#2}}
```

This one compiled, but it wasn't what I wanted
[image]
So I made another command to wrap it.

```
\newcommand\mybox[2][]{\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=black!20, inner sep=2pt, anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,#1] {#2};\phantom{#2}}
\newcommand{\incode}[2][]{\mybox[#1]{\relscale{0.85}\texttt{#2}}}
```

[image]

I added some relative scaling because the font was bigger than I wanted it to be. The result I got is exactly what I want. However, I want to make these two commands in to one. Some help will be nice.

EDIT: MWE added

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{relsize} % relative scaling for font size

\newcommand\mybox[2][]{\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=black!20, inner sep=2pt, anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,#1] {#2};\phantom{#2}}
\newcommand{\incode}[2][]{\mybox[#1]{\relscale{0.85}\texttt{#2}}}

\begin{document}
Example \incode{0.2example} example
\end{document}
```

Comment: It will more easy to answer you, if you will provide an MWE with use of your commands. Now, if one like to help you, is forced to write test document from scratch :-(. Help us to help you  :-)

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for the input! I'll the MWE to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for adding MWE!

A possible solution is simple: insert definition of second command to the first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\mybox[2][]{\tikz[overlay]
    \node[rounded corners=1mm, fill=black!20, inner sep=2pt, anchor=text,
          #1] {\relscale{0.85}\texttt{#2}};\phantom{#2}}

\begin{document}
some text \mybox{0.2example} some text 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: and example to use option of command:

```
\begin{document}
some text \mybox[draw=red]{0.2example} some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\incode}[1][]{on line, enhanced, colback=black!20, fontupper=\sffamily\small, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=2pt, left=2pt, right=2pt, top=2pt, bottom=2pt, frame hidden,#1} 

\begin{document}
Example \incode{0.2example} example \incode[colback=red!30]{0.2example}
\end{document}
```

[image]