# Beamer: highlighting text with colored background through which surrounding text can be seen

Tags: beamer, highlighting, tcolorbox

On some slides I'd like to highlight some text by using a colored background, like so:
[image: text with some words highlighted]

I've exaggerated the width of the border around the text in this example to indicate the effect I want.

I produced this example manually.  I'd like to have a macro `\highlighton` so that I can produce the effect by writing `` \highlighton<1>{`to protrude out'} ``.  The wonderful package `tcolorbox` provides macros that almost do the trick.  Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{times}
\def\highlighton<#1>#2{%
  \alt<#1>{\tcbox[enhanced,boxrule=0pt,colback=red!50,interior style=
  {opacity=0.7},frame style={opacity=0.5},nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,shrink
  tight,extrude by=5mm]{#2}}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\textbf{Extrude}, \textit{v}.\ trans. \textbf{1}.\ To thrust (a person) out or forth;
to urge or force out; to expel.  \textbf{a}.\ with obj.\ a person.  \textbf{b}.\ with
obj.\ a material thing; in mod.\ use esp.\ to exclude (an embryo, ova, etc.). Also 
occas.\ with sense \highlighton<1>{`to protrude out'}.  \textbf{c}. with an immaterial 
thing as obj. \textbf{d}.\ To shape (metals, plastics, etc.)\ by forcing them through 
dies. \textbf{2}.\ intr.\ for refl. To protrude out. rare.

\pause

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This code (in which `extrude by 5mm` generates the border) produces the following output.  Text *before* the highlighted text is "dimmed", but text *after* the highlighted text isn't.  Is there a way to produce exactly the effect I want?

[image]

Comment: You would need to create the red box after the next line of text is produced. I do not have the skills to tell you how to achieve this. Maybe, you would need to consider 2 compilation runs and write relevant information in the auxiliary file. There is this "overlay" option in Tikz that could be useful as well.

Answer (score 10):

My answer is using the same idea as Claudio Fiandrino did. But it uses `tcolorbox` (v2.61) and you may use as many highlights as you want on a page.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{times}
\def\remember#1#2{%
  \tcbox[enhanced,remember as={#1},frame hidden,interior hidden,boxrule=0pt,nobeforeafter,
    tcbox raise base,shrink tight]{#2}%
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/myremember/#1}{#2}%
}
\def\highlighton<#1>#2{%
  \alt<#1>{\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\node at (#2){%
  \tcbox[enhanced,boxrule=0pt,colback=red!50,interior style={opacity=0.7},
         frame style={opacity=0.5},nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,shrink tight,
         extrude by=5mm]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/myremember/#2}}};}{}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\textbf{Extrude}, \textit{v}.\ trans. \textbf{1}.\ To thrust (a person) out or forth;
to urge or force out; to expel.  \textbf{a}.\ with obj.\ a person.  \textbf{b}.\ with
obj.\ a material thing; in mod.\ use esp.\ to exclude (an embryo, ova, etc.). Also
occas.\ with sense \remember{protrude}{`to protrude out'}.  \textbf{c}. with an immaterial
thing as obj. \textbf{d}.\ To shape \remember{etc}{(metals, plastics, etc.)}\ by forcing them through
dies. \textbf{2}.\ intr.\ for refl. To protrude out. rare.%
\highlighton<2>{protrude}
\highlighton<3>{etc}

\pause
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, I was also thinking about using keys to store text correctly, but you were faster.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino It's nice to have both approaches here. Your TikZ only solution is presumably better for people who don't use `tcolorbox` at other places in the text - one package less to include ;-)

Comment: That's terrific!  Is it possible to make \remember store/write the \highlighton commands and have them automatically executed at \end{frame}?  Then one would not have to type the \highlighton commands explicitly.  Icing on the cake really, but it would be nice!

Comment: @MartinJ.Osborne The next days, I will not have the time to try something, but a rough idea is to collect all that has to be done by appending to a macro. Finally, this macro may be hooked into `\end{frame}`.

Comment: A couple of points: (1) If I say `\((1,\remember{minusone}{\(-1\)})\)` (and put `\highlighton<1>{minusone}` at the end) then the "-1" is dimmed as well as the surrounding text. (2) In the version of the macro in my original post, `\((1,\highlighton<1>{\(-1\)})\)` produces a "Bad math delimiter" error.  That can be avoided with `\((1,\highlighton<1>{\hbox{\(-1\)}})\)`. (a) Is that the right way to do it?  (b) In this case, the colored box has slightly greater depth when it contains `\(-1\)` than when it contains `\(1\)` (so that it doesn't line up with adjacent highlighted positive numbers).

Comment: If you want to highlight math stuff, then have a look to the [`hf-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz) package. There are several examples, for instance see [Beamer: highlighting aligned math with overlay](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52598/13304).

Comment: @MartinJ.Osborne I've tried to automate the highlighting but I fear I have not found anything working in reasonable. The main trouble is to save and restore the slide numbers such that `beamer` does not get puzzled. For the math mode, there also seem to be some problems which do not appear without saving. A workaround is to use `\((1,\)\remember{minusone}{\(-1\)}\()\)` which is not very nice but works ...

Comment: I appreciate your efforts!  Thanks for the workaround.

Answer (score 9):

More difficult than what I originally thought. The problem lies in the fact that if one performs operations *within* the text, the opacity is not preserved uniformly in the box. Hence the need to mark somehow the text to be highlighted and to perform *later* the actual highlighting.

This is a possible solution with TikZ only:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\newcounter{storetxt}
\newcounter{showtxt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex] 
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};%
\stepcounter{storetxt}
\global\@namedef{text@\thestoretxt\expandafter}\expandafter{#2}% storing text
}

\newcommand<>{\highlighton}[1]{
\stepcounter{showtxt}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
\edef\txt{\@nameuse{text@\theshowtxt}}% retrieve the correct text
\node[opacity=0.8,text opacity=1,rounded corners,
minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1.5cm,% size of the box
background fill=red!50,fill on=#2,% box visibility
visible on=#2% we need this to have the filling only in some overlays,
% otherwise the opacity would affect all overlays
]at(#1){\txt};
}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\textbf{Extrude}, \textit{v}.\ trans. \textbf{1}.\ To thrust (a person) out or forth;
to urge or force out; to expel.  \textbf{a}.\ with obj.\ a person.  \textbf{b}.\ with
obj.\ a material thing; in mod.\ use esp.\ to exclude (an embryo, ova, etc.). Also 
occas.\ with sense \tikzmark{mark}{`to protrude out'}.  \textbf{c}. with an immaterial 
thing as obj. \textbf{d}.\ To shape \tikzmark{m2}{(metals, plastics, etc.)}\ by forcing them through 
dies. \textbf{2}.\ intr.\ for refl. To protrude out. rare.

\highlighton<2>{mark}% important to have it here after the text
\highlighton<3>{m2}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: of course, "protrude" means "stick out", so "protrude out" presumably means "stick out out".

Comment: @wasteofspace The definition comes from the OED, so you need to take that up with them :)

Answer (score 5):

A similar effect can be achieved with the `spot` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{spot}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\textbf{Extrude}, \textit{v}.\ trans. \textbf{1}.\ To thrust (a person) out or forth;
to urge or force out; to expel.  \textbf{a}.\ with obj.\ a person.  \textbf{b}.\ with
obj.\ a material thing; in mod.\ use esp.\ to exclude (an embryo, ova, etc.). Also 
occas.\ with sense \spot<1>(foo){`to protrude out'}.  \textbf{c}. with an immaterial 
thing as obj. \textbf{d}.\ To shape (metals, plastics, etc.)\ by forcing them through 
dies. \textbf{2}.\ intr.\ for refl. To protrude out. rare.

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]