# Cannot use the hobby package with MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: miktex, hobby

I was directed to use the `hobby` package from a previous question of mine: [Drawing a bent path as a loop in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161256/drawing-a-bent-path-as-a-loop-in-tikz/161270)

However, I just don't seem to get the package to work. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,png]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
\draw (0,0) .. (1,1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in the following error message:

```
mwe.tex:6: Undefined control sequence
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

What particularly bothers me here is that LaTeX does not give me information about which control sequence actually is undefined.

The following version strings are in the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.11.5)  19 FEB 2014 15:40
entering extended mode
**mwe.tex
(<path>\mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
```

I am using the latest version of `hobby`, 2014-01-24 as installed by the miktex package manager. I'm using Windows 7 x64.

Also, since this paper will be submitted to a journal, is using the `hobby` package a bad idea? What are the chances that the journal would not be able to compile the document?

Comment: Did you install the package via the package manager of MikteX (admin one)?

Comment: For the last point, you can create a standalone document and include in you journal paper the resulting pdf as a figure.

Comment: @percusse I did install it with the admin miktex package manager. I have also installed a couple of l3 packages to see if it helped.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino thanks! I did not know that I can compile standalone figures as pdf before using them in the document.

Comment: There is also the possibility, that you have to install/update the package as user.

Comment: @Johannes_B amazing, thanks! That was the issue at hand. I must admit that I often find MiKTeX confusing (I have much more experience with Unix-based LaTeX). Can I award the answer to you even when you replied with a comment?

Comment: I use the externalisation feature of `TikZ` to ensure that a journal (or the arXiv) can use any pictures that I create.  If you do use `hobby` to generate a picture for your paper, send me a link to the paper!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MikTeX can be quite complicated sometimes.
Installing a basic MikTeX as Admin gives you just the basi packages. Running as user and having »Install packages on the fly« activated, all downloaded and installed packages now are in a User tree.

Updating as admin won't have any effect on them, so *usually a user update is needed as well*.

Another possibility is to install packages manually. Usually one can download all files relating to one package from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/). Stefan Kottwitz once gave a [good summary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2066/37907). But beware, installing packages manually most likely leaves you with unresolved dependencies (one package needing another one to work).

Comment: See also [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67712).