# How do I color one line of a display equation?

Tags: equations, color

I want to color only one line of this display equation:

```
\begin{align*}
  i_{fb} &= - \frac{v_o}{Z_F} \\
  F(s) = \frac{i_{fb}}{v_o} &= - \frac{1}{Z_F} \\
  \color{red} F(s) &= - \frac{1 + sR_F C_F}{R_F}
\end{align*}
```

How do I do it? The above example only provides color to `F(s)`. Enclosing whole line in `{}` causes *ref* to appear at the right side.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `color` package and do

```
\color{red} F(s) &\color{red}= - \frac{1 + sR_F C_F}{R_F}
```

Comment: So `\color{...}` does not work across alignment columns?

Comment: @Kit No, each cell is a group

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`hf-tikz`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/hf-tikz) package, which was built as a result of [Beamer: highlighting aligned math with overlay](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52598/beamer-highlighting-aligned-math-with-overlay).

[image: screenshot]

Here's a MWE- note that I had to use `\tikzmarkin{c}(0.1,-0.4)(-0.1,0.5)` to get the boundaries corrected- you might want to adjust them further as you see fit :)

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    i_{fb}                                 & = - \frac{v_o}{Z_F}                         \\
    F(s) = \frac{i_{fb}}{v_o}              & = - \frac{1}{Z_F}                           \\
    \tikzmarkin{c}(0.1,-0.4)(-0.1,0.5)F(s) & = - \frac{1 + sR_F C_F}{R_F}\tikzmarkend{c}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```