# hf-tikz package: error with custom colors and overlay in beamer class

Tags: beamer, highlighting, hf-tikz

Consider the following MWE from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52598/beamer-highlighting-aligned-math-with-overlay):

> **Solution with the [`hf-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz) package**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[beamer]{hf-tikz}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\begin{document}

\section{Mysection}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}{The equations}
\begin{block}{}
 \begin{align}
   \tikzmarkin<1>{a}a_i\tikzmarkend{a} + b_j = 10 & \forall i\in I, j\in J \\
   \tikzmarkin<2>{c}c_j + d_j + \tikzmarkin<1>{b}a_i\tikzmarkend{b} >= 30 & \forall i\in I, j\in J\tikzmarkend{c}
 \end{align}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If I try to customize the colors of the highlighting box as per the documentation, I get an error. For instance, if I insert the lines

```
\hfsetfillcolor{blue!10}
\hfsetbordercolor{blue}
```

right before `tikzmarkin<1>` I get the error `! Undefined control sequence`.

Moreover, I also get an error if I remove overlay specifications `<1>` i.e. `! Missing number treated as zero`. This happens when I remove the marker `tikzmarkin<2>{c}` completely, and use `tikzmarkin<1>{a}` without overlay as `tikzmarkin{a}`. From my understanding of the documentation, overlay specifications are only optional and not compulsory. I am using **TeXnicCenter** with **MiKTeX 2.9**.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is twofold here.

First, it looks like you miss the `customcolors` option. Second, if you want the customization to be global, you have to define it in the preamble. Otherwise,

```
\hfsetfillcolor{blue!10}
\hfsetbordercolor{blue}
```

given before a `\tikzmarkin` customize only *that* command and not he subsequent ones.

Try:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[customcolors,beamer]{hf-tikz}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\hfsetfillcolor{blue!10}
\hfsetbordercolor{blue}

\begin{document}

    \section{Mysection}
    \subsection{A subsection}
    \begin{frame}{The equations}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{align}
                \tikzmarkin<1>{a}a_i\tikzmarkend{a} + b_j = 10 & \forall i\in I, j\in J \\
                \tikzmarkin<2>{c}c_j + d_j + \tikzmarkin<1>{b}a_i\tikzmarkend{b} >= 30 & \forall i\in I, j\in J\tikzmarkend{c}
            \end{align}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

The overlay specifications are mandatory only for Beamer class having the `beamer` option enabled. Indeed, the macro is declared as follows:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\tikzmarkin}{r<> o m D(){\belowrightoff} D(){\aboveleftoff}}{%
```

and the `r` type from `xparse` allows to declare a required argument with custom delimiters.

Basically, if you do not specify the `beamer` option and you do not insert overlays, your code works.

Comment: Thanks, this resolves the first issue. How about the overlay issue?

Comment: @AdeelSabir: You're welcome. For the overlays, they are mandatory.. the definition through xparse makes use of the `r` (required with delimiters) type: `\NewDocumentCommand{\tikzmarkin}{r<> o m D(){\belowrightoff} D(){\aboveleftoff}}{%`

Comment: Elaboration needed. (1) Are they mandatory in all class types, or beamer alone? (2) So, with just a single frame highlighting, one only needs to use overlay option <1>. Beginner level at latex.

Comment: @AdeelSabir: They are mandatory only for Beamer class with `beamer` option enabled. Basically, if you do not specify `beamer` option and you do not insert overlays, your code works.

Comment: If you insert your comments on overlays in the answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @AdeelSabir: please see my updated answer.