# Numbering equations within dynblocks environment

Tags: equations, numbering

I'm trying to number an equation inside an environment created for customed blocks with equations like those contained in [How to adjust the beamer block width to the size of its content?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94481/how-to-adjust-the-latex-beamer-block-width-to-the-size-of-its-content/95395#95395). But I receive an error when inserting an `\align{}` environment. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The errors are my fault with the code. But we should distinguish:

- the numbering problem;
- the `align` problem.

For what concern the numbering problem it could be easily solved: at the moment equations are not numbered due to the call

```
\opaqueblock<#1>[\wd\mybox]{\[\BODY\]}
```

Of course, replacing `\[\BODY\]` with

```
\opaqueblock<#1>[\wd\mybox]{\begin{equation}\BODY\end{equation}}
```

is of help, but we still missing the fact that we previously measure the width of `$\BODY$` without numbers, so the width of the box is wrong. A workaround is:

```
\NewEnviron{cdyn}[1]{%
    \sbox{\mybox}{$\BODY \qquad (1)$}%
    \begin{center}
    \begin{dynblock}
    \opaqueblock<#1>[\wd\mybox]{\begin{equation}\BODY\end{equation}}
    \end{dynblock}
    \end{center}
}{}%
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[customcolors,shadow,roundedcorners]{dynblocks}
% setting the block body color
\usebeamercolor{block body}
\definecolor{my block body}{named}{bg}
\setbordercolor{my block body}
\setblockcolor{my block body}

% new enviroment always centered

\usepackage{environ}
\newsavebox\mybox
% new environment cdyn: #1 => overlay specification

\NewEnviron{cdyn}[1]{%
    \sbox{\mybox}{$\BODY \qquad (1)$}%
    \begin{center}
    \begin{dynblock}
    \opaqueblock<#1>[\wd\mybox]{\begin{equation}\BODY\end{equation}}
    \end{dynblock}
    \end{center}
}{}%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt

\begin{cdyn}{1-}
c^2=a^2+b^2
\end{cdyn}

\begin{cdyn}{2-}
x+y=400
\end{cdyn}

\begin{cdyn}{3-}
\sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}+
\sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\label{eq:sum}
\end{cdyn}

\begin{cdyn}{4-}
q_{n+1}=q_n-\Delta_n+\theta_n \qquad \Delta_n=
\begin{cases}
1 \quad q_n>0\\
0 \quad q_n=0
\end{cases}
\end{cdyn}

\only<4->{I'm referring to \eqref{eq:sum}.}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

For the other problem, inserting an `align` environment, unfortunately I don't have a solution. Indeed, just changing

```
\opaqueblock<#1>[\wd\mybox]{\begin{equation}\BODY\end{equation}}
```

with

```
\opaqueblock<#1>[\wd\mybox]{\begin{align}\BODY\end{align}}
```

is not sufficient. Actually, it works with the example provided above, but if you change

```
\begin{cdyn}{3-}
\sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}+
\sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\label{eq:sum}
\end{cdyn}
```

into

```
\begin{cdyn}{3-}
\sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\\
\sum_{lu _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\label{eq:sum}
\end{cdyn}
```

you will receive these errors

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.54 \end{frame}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.54 \end{frame}

I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.


! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.54 \end{frame}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.54 \end{frame}

I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

The problem here is how the box is measured:

```
\sbox{\mybox}{$\BODY + \qquad (1)$}%
```

does not work with environments that break the line (I suppose) and I don't know how to push something like that in a box and measure its width. Of course, you could always do it manually:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{dynblock}
\opaqueblock<3->[0.8\textwidth]{%
\begin{align}
\sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\\
\sum_{lu _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\label{eq:sum}
\end{align}
}
\end{dynblock}
\end{center}
```

A mwe for completeness:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[customcolors,shadow,roundedcorners]{dynblocks}
% setting the block body color
\usebeamercolor{block body}
\definecolor{my block body}{named}{bg}
\setbordercolor{my block body}
\setblockcolor{my block body}

% new enviroment always centered

\usepackage{environ}
\newsavebox\mybox
% new environment cdyn: #1 => overlay specification

\NewEnviron{cdyn}[1]{%
    \sbox{\mybox}{$\BODY \qquad (1)$}%
    \begin{center}
    \begin{dynblock}
    \opaqueblock<#1>[\wd\mybox]{\begin{equation}\BODY\end{equation}}
    \end{dynblock}
    \end{center}
}{}%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt

\begin{cdyn}{1-}
c^2=a^2+b^2
\end{cdyn}

\begin{cdyn}{2-}
x+y=400
\end{cdyn}

\begin{center}
\begin{dynblock}
\opaqueblock<3->[0.35\textwidth]{%
\begin{align}
\sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\\
\sum_{lu _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\label{eq:sum}
\end{align}
}
\end{dynblock}
\end{center}

\begin{cdyn}{4-}
q_{n+1}=q_n-\Delta_n+\theta_n \qquad \Delta_n=
\begin{cases}
1 \quad q_n>0\\
0 \quad q_n=0
\end{cases}
\end{cdyn}

\only<4->{I'm referring to \eqref{eq:sum}.}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]