# using tikz for rectangle in matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{equation*}
    U^{k} = \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)] (m)
            {
                z^{k}     &  0 & \cdots & s z^{0} & s z^{1} & \cdots & s z^{k-2} & s    z^{k-1} \\
                z^{k-1} s &  \vdots&    & -\overline{z} & s^{2} z^{0}   & \cdots & s^{2} z^{k-3} & s^{2} z^{k-2} \\
                z^{k-2} s &   & &  & -\overline{z} & s^{2} z^{0} & \cdots & s^{2} z^{k-3} \\
                \vdots    &   & &  &   & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
                z s       & \vdots&  &   & 0 &   & -\overline{z} & s^{2} z^{0} \\
                s         & 0 & \cdots &  &   &   &   & -\overline{z} \\
                0         & 1 &   & 0 &  &  &   &   \\
                \vdots    &   & \ddots & &  &   & 0 &   \\
                0         & 0 &   & 1 &  & &   &   \\
            };
            \draw (m-2-4.north west) rectangle (m-6-8.south east);
            \draw (m-7-2.north west) rectangle (m-9-4.south east);
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}
```

thats my code and the result
[image]

the one rectangle is to small. any ideas?
and to have the "U^k=" in the middle?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may want to have a look to [Array cell highlighting tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83323/13304) although the matrix is not directly typeset with TikZ. Other methods are illustrated in [Highlight elements in the matrix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40028/13304). To have `U^k` in the middle, have a look to [use of tikzpicture matrix in align or gather environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59658/13304).

Answer (score 2):

To bring `U^k=` to the middle use `[baseline={(m.center)}]` as the option to the `\begin{tikzpicture}`. and to make the rectangle bigger use `(m-6-8.south east-|m-2-8.north east)` in

```
 \draw (m-2-4.north west) rectangle (m-6-8.south east-|m-2-8.north east);
```

which means `x` coordinate same as `m-2-8.north east` and `y` coordinate same as that of `m-6-8.south east`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    U^{k} = \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(m.center)}]
            \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)] (m)
            {
                z^{k}     &  0 & \cdots & s z^{0} & s z^{1} & \cdots & s z^{k-2} & s    z^{k-1} \\
                z^{k-1} s &  \vdots&    & -\overline{z} & s^{2} z^{0}   & \cdots & s^{2} z^{k-3} & s^{2} z^{k-2} \\
                z^{k-2} s &   & &  & -\overline{z} & s^{2} z^{0} & \cdots & s^{2} z^{k-3} \\
                \vdots    &   & &  &   & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
                z s       & \vdots&  &   & 0 &   & -\overline{z} & s^{2} z^{0} \\
                s         & 0 & \cdots &  &   &   &   & -\overline{z} \\
                0         & 1 &   & 0 &  &  &   &   \\
                \vdots    &   & \ddots & &  &   & 0 &   \\
                0         & 0 &   & 1 &  & &   &   \\
            };
            \draw (m-2-4.north west) rectangle (m-6-8.south east-|m-2-8.north east);
            \draw (m-7-2.north west) rectangle (m-9-4.south east);
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]` because `m.center` is already the baseline reference.

Comment: @Ignasi I wanted to be explicit ;-). You are right. :-)

Comment: @Ignasi not if you have bottom delimiters or other items inside the picture.

Comment: This one worked very well for me, thank you very much.

Comment: @percusse My fault. I just tested with the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered [`easy`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/easy) bundle in CTAN and this is a good question to test [`easybmat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/easybmat) package.

As usual you need to know columns number but also rows number. It's possible to select different alignemt (l,c,r) for rows and columns. And it's possible to draw paths between elements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{easybmat}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    U^{k} = \left(\begin{BMAT}{cccccccc}{ccccccccc}
                z^{k}     &  0 & \cdots & s z^{0} & s z^{1} & \cdots & s z^{k-2} & s    z^{k-1} \\
                z^{k-1} s &  \vdots&    & -\overline{z} & s^{2} z^{0}   & \cdots & s^{2} z^{k-3} & s^{2} z^{k-2} \\
                z^{k-2} s &   & &  & -\overline{z} & s^{2} z^{0} & \cdots & s^{2} z^{k-3} \\
                \vdots    &   & &  &   & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
                z s       & \vdots&  &   & 0 &   & -\overline{z} & s^{2} z^{0} \\
                s         & 0 & \cdots &  &   &   &   & -\overline{z} \\
                0         & 1 &   & 0 &  &  &   &   \\
                \vdots    &   & \ddots & &  &   & 0 &   \\
                0         & 0 &   & 1 &  & &   &   
    \addpath{(1,0,0)rrruuulllddd}
    \addpath{(3,3,0)rrrrruuuuulllllddddd}
    \end{BMAT}\right)
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This one is also very good, especially that the rectangles don't overlap, merely that the empty space at the top of the big rectangle is a bit out of order

Comment: @mfg And also the right space on the small one. May be it's possible to adjust it but this was my just first test with easybmat and used default parameters.