# Highlighting multiline, centering cells in tabularx with a tikz frame: setting points for the frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularx

So, I've followed [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4850/highlighting-table-cells) to highlight cells in my tabularx-table. This works well for single-"item"-cells and with some `\hfill` it works well enough for ragged-multiline-cells too.

However, with multiline, centering cells, this approach doesn't work at all, as the reference points are set by the first and last word thus drawing a frame cutting throught the text:

[image: bad outcome]

some playing around with newlines yields this result, which is ok, however the "full" line is not really nice:

[image: okish outcome]

So, how could I improve on this? I've tried to get the cell-extents (or at least `\TX@col@width`, but that didn't work for me); `\hphantom` should nominally do, what I want, but I think it doesn't really work in tables.

MWE (the newline/hfill-comments give the "ok" solution. :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand{\tabxmulticol}[3] 
    {\multicolumn{#1}
                 {>{\centering\hsize=\dimexpr#1\hsize+#1\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}#2}
                 {#3}}

\newcommand\marktopleft[1]{%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]%
\coordinate (marker-#1-a) at (0,1.5ex) {};%
\hspace*{\fill}\newline%
}

\newcommand\markbottomright[1]{%
    \newline \hspace*{\fill}
    \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{3mm}{3mm}}
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
        \coordinate (marker-#1-b) at (0,-0.5ex) {};%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,thick,dashed,inner sep=0pt]
        \node[draw,rectangle,fit=(marker-#1-a.center) (marker-#1-b.center)] {};%
}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.24\textwidth}XX}
First row &  & \marktopleft{cella} bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \markbottomright{cella} \\
Second row & 2a & \\
Third row & & 3b \\
Fourth row & \tabxmulticol{2}{X}{\marktopleft{cellb} he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he \markbottomright{cellb}} \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It might be easier if you use a matrix of Ti*k*Z nodes, as proposed in the other answer to the question you link to. For a possible solution using this approach see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83323/47927 .

Comment: Thanks, I've looked into this, but the problem there is, that the multirow/column-cells are not that easy there then. The nicematrix by Imran does it nicely though!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to achieve what you want using the `nicematrix` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{p{0.24\textwidth}X[c]X[c]}[name=MyTbl]
        \RowStyle[cell-space-limits=3mm]{}
        First row &  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
        Second row & 2a & \\
        Third row & & 3b \\
        \RowStyle[cell-space-limits=3mm]{}
        Fourth row & \Block{1-2}{\parbox{8.5cm}{\centering he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he}} &\\
        \CodeAfter
            \tikz \node[draw, dashed, rounded corners, inner ysep=-1mm,rectangle, fit=(MyTbl-1-3)] {};
            \tikz \node[draw, dashed, rounded corners, inner ysep=-1 mm,rectangle, fit=(MyTbl-4-3) (MyTbl-4-2)] {};
    \end{NiceTabularX}
\end{document}
```

`nicematrix` associates a tikz node for every cell of the table and it's possible to use these nodes with tikz. This makes what you want easier. The nodes are accessible with the name `name-i-j` where `name` is the name given to the table (with the optional argument of the environment) and `i` and `j` are the numbers of row and column.

The only downside is that `nicematrix` doesn't yet support automatic linebreak in multi-cell blocks. So, to do that, one needs to insert a `parbox` in a block.

Edit:

It looks better to me if more space is added around every row.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
        {\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 2mm}
        \begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{p{0.24\textwidth}X[c]X[c]}[name=MyTbl2]
            %       \RowStyle[cell-space-limits=3mm]{}
            First row &  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
            Second row & 2a & \\
            Third row & & 3b \\
            %       \RowStyle[cell-space-limits=3mm]{}
            Fourth row & \Block{1-2}{\parbox{8.5cm}{\centering he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he he}} &\\
            \CodeAfter
            \tikz \node[draw, dashed, rounded corners, inner ysep=0mm, rectangle, fit=(MyTbl2-1-3)] {};
            \tikz \node[draw, dashed, rounded corners, inner ysep=0mm, rectangle, fit=(MyTbl2-4-3) (MyTbl2-4-2)] {};
        \end{NiceTabularX}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, it is necessary to compile the code more than once to get the correct result.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great solution! (unfortunately I can't mark it solved)

Comment: Usually, it's good to wait for some time (maybe a day) before accepting, as a better solution may be given. However, I will like to know why you can't accept it as that might help me improve the answer.

Comment: I am a fresh user and accepting so fast is a rookie mistake, SX wants to prevent. On that note: do you know, how to query the width of the X-columns so that you can set up the parbox programatically?

Comment: Regular `X` column width depends on other columns. I don't know how to get exactly the width of the `X` column if there is an `l`,  `c`, or `r` column. But for your case, `\dimexpr \texwidth - 0.24\textwidth - \tabcolsep` should give you the combined width of your two `X` columns. But sadly it doesn't work as expected in the `parbox` (I don't know why).