# How to box the correct answer in Exam class?

Tags: boxes, exam

I have tried using the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{\mbox{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Who is an idot? 
\begin{choices}
\choice Not the writer of this post
\CorrectChoiceEmphasis The writter of this post
\end{choices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: By box you mean put a frame around the correct answer?

Comment: @cgnieder Frame, means to have a border on all 4 sides like a square around the correct answers, then yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a couple of methods:

- simply using an `fbox`
- a `\tikzmark` solution (impossible to resist) based on [A \boxed alternative with nicer spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35217/a-boxed-alternative-with-nicer-spacing/35227#35227).

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\newcommand{\mycorrectchoice}[1]{\CorrectChoice \fbox{#1}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand{\DrawSmartBox}[1][red]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \draw[#1]
      ($(bl)+(-1.75em,1em)$) rectangle
      ($(br)+(0.2em,-0.4em)$);}
}

% \MyCorrectSmartChoice:
% #1 optional argument: aspect customization
% #2 mandatory argument: the answer
\newcommand{\MyCorrectSmartChoice}[2][black]{\CorrectChoice \tikzmark{bl}#2\tikzmark{br}\DrawSmartBox[#1]}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Who is an idot? 
\begin{choices}
\choice Not the writer of this post
\mycorrectchoice{The writter of this post}
\choice Who read this post
\end{choices}
\question Who is an idot? 
\begin{choices}
\choice Not the writer of this post
\MyCorrectSmartChoice[thick,rounded corners,red]{The writter of this post}
\choice Who read this post
\end{choices}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Notice that the example requires two compilation runs because of the `\tikzmark` macro; furthermore, this approach allows to customize the aspect of the box, as did in the example.

Comment: I got emp.tex:0:No file temp.aux.
temp.tex:23:Undefined control sequence. \mycorrectchoice{The writter of this post}
temp.tex:29:Undefined control sequence. ...rrectSmartChoice{The writter of this post}
temp.tex:0: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

Comment: @MaoYiyi: you should compile twice because of the `tikzmark` macro. Does it solve the problem?

Comment: I just push the button to make a pdf.  How does one compile?  I use Kile to write my latex.

Comment: Just push it twice and check that your auxiliary file are not deleted between the two runs. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modification of Claudio's answer. With this modification, if you don't use the `answers` option of the exam class the correct answer is not boxed, you can give the exam to your students, the result is:

[image]

If the `answers` option is used (the syntax is

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
```

) then the correct answers are boxed. The result is:

[image]

The code is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam} %Use the answers option to box correct answers

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand{\DrawSmartBox}[1][red]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \draw[#1]
      ($(bl)+(-1.75em,1em)$) rectangle
      ($(br)+(0.2em,-0.4em)$);}
}

%Here is the modification
\ifprintanswers
% \MyCorrectSmartChoice:
% #1 optional argument: aspect customization
% #2 mandatory argument: the answer
\newcommand{\MyCorrectSmartChoice}[2][black]{\CorrectChoice \tikzmark{bl}#2\tikzmark{br}\DrawSmartBox[#1]}
\else
\newcommand{\MyCorrectSmartChoice}[2][black]{\CorrectChoice #1}
\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Who is an idiot? 
\begin{choices}
\choice Not the writer of this post
\MyCorrectSmartChoice[thick,rounded corners,red]{The writer of this post}
\choice Who read this post
\end{choices}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can this also work with task environment like choice environment?