# How to create an optional argument like the 'correctchoice` command in exam document class?

Tags: macros, exam, questionnaire

I want to create an alternative to `CorrectChoice`. That when `[answers]` command is used it will highlight the correct answer and be printed with the question together. 
I have seen this command by this link [How to box the correct answer in Exam class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81897/how-to-box-the-correct-answer-in-exam-class). it created a command `MyCorrectSmartChoice` I am thinking on if the `[answers]` command will not be included, how will the function(puting the correct answer inside the box) of this particular command be hidden??

example:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question The question is here.

\begin{choices}
\choice one 
\MyCorrectSmartChoice two 
\choice three

\end{choices}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Then if the `[answers]` command will be used, it will be emphasized?

Need some help on this matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `exam` class offers a conditional `\ifprintanswers` which is explained in the [`exam` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/exam) section **8.5 Changes depending on whether or not solutions are being printed**. So you could change the definition of `\MyCorrectSmartChoice` in the linked question as follows:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
% \documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand{\DrawSmartBox}[1][red]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \draw[#1]
      ($(bl)+(-1.75em,1em)$) rectangle
      ($(br)+(0.2em,-0.4em)$);}
}

% \MyCorrectSmartChoice:
% #1 optional argument: aspect customization
% #2 mandatory argument: the answer
\newcommand{\MyCorrectSmartChoice}[2][black]{%
  \ifprintanswers
    \CorrectChoice \tikzmark{bl}#2\tikzmark{br}\DrawSmartBox[#1]%
  \else
    \CorrectChoice #2%
  \fi
}
\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question What's the question? 
\begin{choices}
 \choice How should I know?
 \MyCorrectSmartChoice[thick,rounded corners,red]{What's $6\times7$?}
\end{choices}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

With `answers` option:

[image]

Without `answers` option:

[image]