# Exam Class: Make math expressions in \correctchoice bold

Tags: bold, exam

I'm using the `exam` package to create a mathematics question paper. When printing answers, the `\correctchoice` command makes the choice letter as well as the text in the choice bold. However, it does not make any mathematic expressions bold.

Is there a way to add this to the document? I think the commands `\boldmath` and `\unboldmath` when put around the text will make both normal text and mathematic expressions bold, but I do not know how to "merge" it with the `\correctchoice` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best solution would be to use `\correctchoice` as a hook and tack `\boldmath` and `\unboldmath` onto it that way using a formula of `\edef` and `\expandafter`s that I've yet to grasp/memorize.  See [How to add a hook to a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6698/how-to-add-a-hook-to-a-macro).

In absence of hooking, I would say

```
\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{%
  \ifprintanswers
    \let\oldchoice\choice
    \let\oldcorrectchoice\correctchoice
    \def\choice{\unboldmath\oldchoice}
    \def\correctchoice{\oldcorrectchoice\boldmath}
  \fi}
```

`\noprintanswers`:
[image]

`\printanswers`:
[image]

Comment: This works brilliantly. No need for a new command either. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You already seem to have answers that will work, but the exam class provides a hook for customizing the correct choices.  If you give the command:

```
\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{\bfseries\boldmath}
```

then you'll get what you want.  The default behavior was created with the command here:

```
\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{\bfseries}
```

Comment: If I can believe my eyes, this is a much better solution than mine -- I didn't see anything like this in the manual XD

Comment: @SeanAllred: It's in section 5.6 (Customizations) of examdoc.pdf.  Section 5 discusses multiple choice questions.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99549/how-to-create-an-optional-argument-like-the-correctchoice-command-in-exam-docu?rq=1) I was able to do it.

Adding

```
\newcommand{\MyCorrectChoice}[1]{%
   \ifprintanswers
      \CorrectChoice \boldmath#1\unboldmath%
   \else
      \CorrectChoice #1%
   \fi
}
```

to the preamble fixed my problem.

Comment: What's with the optional argument?

Comment: You're right, there's no need. I tried to change as little as I could of the answer from that question. I'll edit my answer now.