# How do I add a \vector to a table?

Tags: tables, diagrams, vector

I am trying to make a table that shows how an element moves from location in the table to another. I would like to add a vector that starts at the first element and goes to the second element.

How do I do this?

I've tried putting the table in a picture but I get the error: Not in outer par mode.

```
\begin{figure}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\begin{picture}(500,400)
\put(20,-10){\vector(1,-1){5}}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
\textbf{Something here} &  \\ \hline
A & F \\ 
B & A \\ 
C & G \\ 
D & H \\ 
E & I%
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{picture}
\end{figure}
```

I want a vector pointing from A in left column to A in right column.

And I've tried putting the picture in a cell but the `\vector` commands don't show up in the PDF.

I have also searched Google but can't find how to do it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. For example, where do you use `\vector` or what package defines this command? Also, does this `\vector` stretch in a straight line from one cell to the other?

Comment: Added MWE (which is misleading because it doesn't work) and yes it does stretch in a straight line from one cell to the other.

Vector is a part of LaTeX and is not a part of any package that I know of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Andrew Stacey's tried and tested `tikzmark` idea, first posted here

[Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570)

and repeated in many examples since.

The idea is to set a `node` at each of the places in your table, and then  connect the two nodes afterwards (using `overlay` and `remember picture`). You can tweak the placement of the connections using the `calc` tikz library.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1){};}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
    \textbf{Something here} &  \\ \hline
    A\tikzmark{firstmarker} & F \\ 
    B & A\tikzmark{secondmarker} \\ 
    C & G \\ 
    D & H \\ 
    E & I%
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[red,->] ($(firstmarker)+(.2em,0.5em)$)--($(secondmarker)+(-.6em,0.5em)$);
\end{document}
```

Comment: I haven't heard of tikzmark, but that is exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @Fred you're welcome! Note that `tikzmark` is just the name of the newcommand- it's the `tikz` package that does the work.