# Draw a line through one column of a matrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices, rules, cancel

I'd like to "cancel" (draw a line through) a column of a matrix (using `\begin{pmatrix}..\end{pmatrix}`). How can I do this?

Comment: Related Questions: [Draw a vertical line over the entries of a column in an array](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196258/draw-a-vertical-line-over-the-entries-of-a-column-in-an-array) and [Draw a horizonal line over the entries of a row in an array](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79741/draw-a-horizonal-line-over-the-entries-of-a-row-in-an-array).

Comment: I think I win for seniority :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The usual TikZ answer using `\tikzmark` to mark the top and bottom points where you want the line to be drawn:

[image]

### Notes:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.

### References:

- `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1570/4301).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base] (#1) {$#2$};}

\newcommand{\DrawLine}[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[#1] (#2.north) -- (#3.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
  \tikzmark{topA}{a} & \tikzmark{topB}b & {0} \\
  a & b & 0 \\
  a & b & 0 \\
  \tikzmark{bottomA}{c} & \tikzmark{bottomB}d & {1}
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\DrawLine[red, thick, opacity=0.5]{topA}{bottomA}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 20):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b & c  \\
  d & e & f\makebox(-6,0){\rule[1ex]{0.4pt}{3\normalbaselineskip}}\\
  g & h & i
\end{pmatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

And a line only through f and i:

```
d & e & f\makebox(-6,0){\rule[-7ex]{0.4pt}{2\normalbaselineskip}}\\
```

[image]

Comment: can you show me how draw an horizontal line to cancel the first row? Merry christmas!

Comment: for example `\rlap{\rule[0.6ex]{1.3cm}{0.4pt}}a & b & c  \\ `

Comment: Very good @Herbert!

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\settodepth{\dimen0}{$\begin{array}[t]{l}1\\2\\3\\4\end{array}$}
\addtolength{\dimen0}{2ex}
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b & 0 \\
  a & b & 0 \\
  a & b & 0 \\
  \smash{\makebox[0pt][l]{\kern2pt\rule[-.8ex]{0.4pt}{\dimen0}}}
  c & d & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

More can be added if you define better your needs

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rudimentary way to do this with a regular `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f \\
  g & h & i
\end{pmatrix}\]

\[\left(\begin{array}{@{}cc@{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}|@{\hspace{-.5\tabcolsep}}c@{}}
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f \\
  g & h & i
\end{array}\right)\]
\end{document}
```

This works well for single-entry columns. If you have wider columns, more modification of the lengths are required.