# An environment of tcolorbox to draw vertical lines configurable in numbers and in color?

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, variable, calc, technical-environment

I was inspired by the code of Ignasi in the following link:

[Mark (highlight) a paragraph (\item{…}) with a squiggly line across several pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595372/mark-highlight-a-paragraph-item-with-a-squiggly-line-across-several-page)

I modified it to do the following command:
which draws `#1` parallel lines with the same color `#2` along the text in the left margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc}

\newcommand{\mycolorbarmarg}[2]{
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{%
    enhanced, blank, breakable,
    overlay ={\foreach \t in {0,...,#1}{
        \draw[decorate,ultra thick,#2] ([xshift=-3-\t mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=-3-\t mm]frame.south west);},
}}
\begin{mybox}
#3
\end{mybox}
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\mycolorbarmarg{2}{red}{\lipsum[1-5]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But this command cannot be called more than once, otherwise, the following error message appears:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \mybox already defined.

Error when I call at least twice \mycolorbarmarg 

\mycolorbarmarg{2}{red}{\lipsum[1-5]}

\mycolorbarmarg{2}{red}{\lipsum[1-5]}
```

From what I understand: the command `\mycolorbarmarg` wants to override the `mybox` command, which does not allow it!

The ideal would be a `tcolorbox` environment with parameters `#1` (number of lines) and `#2` (their color), something like this, **but of course not correct code**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc}

%%%%% something like this:

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[3]{%
    enhanced, blank, breakable,
    overlay ={\foreach \t in {0,...,#1}{ %
         \draw[decorate,ultra thick,#2] ([xshift=-1-\t mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=-1-\t mm]frame.south west);},
}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
% for some environment like this :
\begin{mybox}[#1,#2]\lipsum[1]\end{mybox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I first thought of this which solves the calling problem but where a lot of `newtcolorbox` are created:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc}

\newcounter{tmp}
\setcounter{tmp}{1}
\newcommand{\mycolorbarmarg}[2]{
\newtcolorbox{mybox\thetmp}[1][]{%
    enhanced, blank, breakable,
    overlay ={\foreach \t in {0,...,#1}{
        \draw[decorate,ultra thick,#2] ([xshift=-3-\t mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=-3-\t mm]frame.south west);},
}}
\begin{mybox\thetmp}
#3
\end{mybox\thetmp}
\addtocounter{tmp}{1}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\mycolorbarmarg{2}{red}{\lipsum[1-5]}
\mycolorbarmarg{1}{blue}{\lipsum[1]}
\mycolorbarmarg{3}{black}{\lipsum[1-5]}
\mycolorbarmarg{0}{green}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Creating so many `\newtcolorbox` bothers me... It would be much better to have an environment or command from the `tcolorboxù package directly that would use` #1`and`#2` as parameters!

While writing my request, analyzing my problem, and leafing through the instructions for the `tcolorbox` package, I found `\renewtcolorbox` and it allowed me to compose this which also works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc}

%%%%% necessary for renewtcolorbox to have something to redefine
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
enhanced, blank, breakable,
    overlay ={%
        \draw[decorate,ultra thick,black] ([xshift=-3 mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=-3 mm]frame.south west);},
}
%%%%% a command width \renewtcolorbox 
\newcommand{\mycolorbarmarg}[2]{
\renewtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{%
    enhanced, blank, breakable,
    overlay ={\foreach \t in {0,...,#1}{
        \draw[decorate,ultra thick,#2] ([xshift=-3-\t mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=-3-\t mm]frame.south west);},
}}
\begin{mybox}
#3
\end{mybox}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\mycolorbarmarg{2}{red}{\lipsum[1-5]}
\mycolorbarmarg{1}{blue}{\lipsum[1]}
\mycolorbarmarg{3}{black}{\lipsum[1-5]}
\mycolorbarmarg{0}{green}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I prefer this but it's also not a `tcolorbox` environment with `#1` and `#2` as parameters.

Do you know if it is possible to make such an environment with `tcolorbox`?

I would like to use `\begin{mybox}[#1,#2]\lipsum[1-]\end{mybox}`
with `#1` for the number of lines, and `#2` for their color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc}

\newtcolorbox{mycolorbarmarg}[2]{
    enhanced, blank, breakable,
    overlay = {
        \foreach \t in {0,...,#1}{
            \draw[decorate,ultra thick, #2]
                ([xshift=-3-\t mm]frame.north west)
                --
                ([xshift=-3-\t mm]frame.south west);
        },
    }
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{mycolorbarmarg}{2}{red}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\end{mycolorbarmarg}

\begin{mycolorbarmarg}{4}{blue}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\end{mycolorbarmarg}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks!