# Is there any latex package to format emails?

Tags: packages

I am writing a document using Latex and I need to attach a few emails (sender, receiver, body message, etc...).

Currently, I am manually editing the fields so that they look more readable. Such as bold-facing the **From:** and **To:**, adding href to emails, etc. I wonder if there is any Latex package that automatically formats emails in decent way?

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to format an email conversation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68251/134144)

Comment: @leandriis Thanks! Unfortunately the answer from that question suggests manual editing, pretty much of what I already have.

Comment: If your question is just about single emails it might be quite easy to wtire a custom environment that does all the required fromatting for you. If your emails also contain multiple answers and replies this task might be a bit more complicated. Could you maybe add information on that and also add an example email and how you format it to your question?