# Using shortcut with argument in tcolorbox

Tags: environments, tcolorbox

I want to do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate} %for printing the date
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} %for color names
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\MyArgument}{Datum: \printdate{#1}}

\newtcolorbox{MyBox1}[1]{colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!75!black, title=\MyArgument }

%some more "\newtcolorbox{...}" with different colors, but all with title=\MyArgument

\begin{document}

 \begin{MyBox}{2014-02-11}
  \lipsum
 \end{MyBox}

\end{document}
```

The output should be a box with the title "Datum: 11. Februar 2014" (German date format)

The purpose is that I want to be able to change the title of all boxes at the same time. How can I do that?

Comment: Providing a compilable example that begins with `\documentclass` is extremely helpful to those who wish to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I added it now. A also changed the date format to German because this led to some confusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[english]{isodate} %for printig the date
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\MyCom[1]{Datum:~\numdate{#1}}

\newtcolorbox{MyBoxi}[1]{
  colback=red!5!white,
  colframe=red!75!black,
  title=\MyCom{#1}
}
\newtcolorbox{MyBoxii}[1]{
  colback=cyan!5!white,
  colframe=cyan!75!black,
  title=\MyCom{#1}
}

\begin{document}

 \begin{MyBoxi}{2014-02-11}
  \lipsum[4]
 \end{MyBoxi}

 \begin{MyBoxii}{2014-02-11}
  \lipsum[4]
 \end{MyBoxii}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest `\usepackage[german]{isodate}` and `\newcommand\MyCom[1]{Datum:~\numdate\printdate{#1}}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes suggestion accepted :-)

Comment: The `\numdate` gives the date as `11.02.2014` instead of `11. Februar 2014`, as requested by the OP.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I am not sure whether the OP is also asking for a way to change the date format. I'll use your suggestion for `\numdate` as well. Thanks.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Sorry for the confusing formulation! This seems to be the essential part I was asking for:

`\makeatletter
\def\iso@isodash{mmmmm}
\makeatother`

Can you explain what it does?

Comment: @MaxD Sorry about that. Those lines were only remnant code from some test; those lines, in fact, do nothing (at least not with the settings in my example code). I've removed those spurious lines from my answer. By the way, does the answer solve your problem or is it something else what you need?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, it does, thanks again! The essential thing was that I simply didn't come up with the idea of adding the argument again in `title=\MyCom{#1}`. Sorry, a stupid question...

If anyone is interested, I needed this to add a function to my email chronicle [(Chronicle of email correspondences)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159369/chronicle-of-email-correspondences) for threads in online forums where more than two people are writing.

Comment: @MaxD Ah, OK. I remember your Chronicle of email correspondence :-)