# how to implement something that looks like email in memoir class

Tags: formatting, memoir

I'm writing some fiction and typesetting it using texlive. I want to include a number of "emails" as part of the story but I'm a bit stuck how best to achieve this. My first attempt looks like this:

```
\rule{250pt}{1pt}
\newline
\texttt{From: HamiltonP, Beth\newline
To: Croft, Norrie\newline
Date: September 12th 2014\newline
Subject: Paris\newline
\newline
<some paragraph text>
\newline
<more paragraph text> }
\newline

\rule{250pt}{1pt}
\newline
```

obviously a monospace font is not particular appropriate for modern emails but it should be in a different font from the main text (maybe a sans serif for instance) and probably a different (smaller?) size.

Is there a straightforward way to do this? has someone done something similar before?

Comment: Basically you want to define an environment in which to put the mail, right? Are you settled on the looks?

Comment: Related: [Typesetting email with internet-style quoting using LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49587/5764)

Comment: I saw the "internet-style" quoting answer when I was searching for a solution. I didn't fully understand it but it didn't seem to produce something that would look good in a fiction setting. And no, I'm not settled on the looks really. It just needs to look like email and stand out from the body text. :)

Comment: As I said in my answer, my favorite kind of question!

Comment: @susie I've removed your 'signature' from the post as your name appears as a little icon in the bottom-right anyway.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is my favorite kind of question!

### Update

If you get some nice icons related to emails, then you can add them to the design (I got some icons from [iconfinder](https://www.iconfinder.com/) for my example). Here's the `tcolorbox` version (see below) with an icon bar added:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}% to generate text for the example

\definecolor{myboxgray}{RGB}{216,207,190}
\definecolor{mybackgray}{RGB}{243,232,223}
\definecolor{mybargray}{RGB}{192,185,169}

\newcommand\mybox[1]{
  \node[text width=2cm] {\strut#1};
}

\tikzset{
mybox/.style={
  draw=myboxgray!70!black,
  fill=myboxgray,
  text width=1.3cm,
  anchor=north west,
  align=center,
  inner ysep=2pt,
  font=\sffamily\small  
  },
myinfobox/.style={
  draw=myboxgray!70!black,
  text width=\textwidth-2cm-1pt,
  anchor=north west,
  inner ysep=2pt,
  fill=white,
  font=\sffamily\small  
  },
mybar/.style={
  draw=mybargray!70!black,
  fill=mybargray,
  text width=\textwidth-0.666em,
  minimum height=20pt,
  anchor=south west,
  outer sep=0pt
  }  
}

\newtcolorbox{mytemail}[5][]{
breakable,
pad after break=-63pt,
freelance,
colback=white,
left=0pt,
right=0pt,
outer arc=0pt,
arc=0pt,
colframe=gray,
colback=mybackgray,
boxrule=0.5pt,
top=80pt,
left=4pt,
right=4pt,
before=\par\vskip26pt,
fontupper=\sffamily\small,
overlay unbroken and first={
  \draw[draw=myboxgray!70!black,fill=mybargray]
    ([yshift=20pt]frame.north west)
      rectangle
    (frame.north east);
  \node[anchor=west]
    at ([yshift=9pt]frame.north west)
    (send) {\includegraphics[height=14pt]{send}};
  \node[anchor=west,font=\sffamily\small]
    at (send.east)
    (sendtext) {Send};   
  \node[anchor=west]
    at ([xshift=10pt]sendtext.east)
    (cancel) {\includegraphics[height=14pt]{cancel}};
  \node[anchor=west,font=\sffamily\small]
    at (cancel.east)
    (canceltext) {Cancel};   
  \node[anchor=west]
    at ([xshift=10pt]canceltext.east)
    (save) {\includegraphics[height=14pt]{save}};
  \node[anchor=west,font=\sffamily\small]
    at (save.east)
    (savetext) {Save Draft};   
  \node[anchor=west]
    at ([xshift=10pt]savetext.east)
    (add) {\includegraphics[height=14pt]{attachment}};
  \node[anchor=west,font=\sffamily\small]
    at (add.east)
    (addtext) {Add Attachment};   
  \node[mybox]
    at ([shift={(2pt,-2pt)}]frame.north west) 
    (from) {\strut From:};
  \node[mybox,below=2pt of from] 
    (to) {\strut To:};
  \node[mybox,below=2pt of to] 
    (date) {\strut Date:};
  \node[mybox,below=2pt of date] 
    (subj) {\strut Subject:};
  \node[draw,myinfobox,right=2pt of from] 
    (fromtext) {\strut #2};
  \node[draw,myinfobox,right=2pt of to] 
    (totext) {\strut #3};
  \node[draw,myinfobox,right=2pt of date] 
    (datetext) {\strut #4};
  \node[draw,myinfobox,right=2pt of subj] 
    (subjtext) {\strut #5};
  \draw[myboxgray!70!black,fill=white] 
    ([shift={(2pt,-74pt)}]interior.north west) 
      rectangle 
    ([shift={(-2pt,2pt)}]interior.south east); 
  },
overlay middle and last={
  \draw[myboxgray!70!black,fill=white] 
    ([shift={(2pt,-2pt)}]interior.north west) 
      rectangle 
    ([shift={(-2pt,2pt)}]interior.south east); 
  }  
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{mytemail}{HamiltonP, Beth}{Croft, Norrie}{September 12th 2014}{Paris}
\lipsum[4]
\end{mytemail}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

### First version

Here's one possibility in which I simulated the style used for e-mails by some providers. I present two versions; one using `tcolorbox` and another one using `mdframed`. Both versions allow page breaks.

First, I used the powerful [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package:

[image]

All the job is done by a `mytemail` environment with four mandatory arguments:

```
\begin{mytemail}{<from>}{<to>}{<date>}{<subject>
<text>
\end{mytemail}
```

an optional argument allows to pass eventual additional options to the tcolorbox defined. The box in the example was produced using

```
\begin{mytemail}{HamiltonP, Beth}{Croft, Norrie}{September 12th 2014}{Paris}
\lipsum[4]
\end{mytemail}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}% to generate text for the example

\definecolor{myboxgray}{RGB}{216,207,190}
\definecolor{mybackgray}{RGB}{243,232,223}

\newcommand\mybox[1]{
  \node[text width=2cm] {\strut#1};
}

\tikzset{
mybox/.style={
  draw=myboxgray!70!black,
  fill=myboxgray,
  text width=1.3cm,
  anchor=north west,
  align=center,
  inner ysep=2pt,
  font=\sffamily\small  
  },
myinfobox/.style={
  draw=myboxgray!70!black,
  text width=\textwidth-2cm-1pt,
  anchor=north west,
  inner ysep=2pt,
  fill=white,
  font=\sffamily\small  
  }
}

\newtcolorbox{mytemail}[5][]{
breakable,
pad after break=-63pt,
freelance,
colback=white,
left=0pt,
right=0pt,
outer arc=0pt,
arc=0pt,
colframe=gray,
colback=mybackgray,
boxrule=0.5pt,
top=80pt,
left=4pt,
right=4pt,
before=\par\medskip,
fontupper=\sffamily\small,
overlay unbroken and first={
  \node[mybox]
    at ([shift={(2pt,-2pt)}]frame.north west) 
    (from) {\strut From:};
  \node[mybox,below=2pt of from] 
    (to) {\strut To:};
  \node[mybox,below=2pt of to] 
    (date) {\strut Date:};
  \node[mybox,below=2pt of date] 
    (subj) {\strut Subject:};
  \node[draw,myinfobox,right=2pt of from] 
    (fromtext) {\strut #2};
  \node[draw,myinfobox,right=2pt of to] 
    (totext) {\strut #3};
  \node[draw,myinfobox,right=2pt of date] 
    (datetext) {\strut #4};
  \node[draw,myinfobox,right=2pt of subj] 
    (subjtext) {\strut #5};
  \draw[myboxgray!70!black,fill=white] 
    ([shift={(2pt,-74pt)}]interior.north west) 
      rectangle 
    ([shift={(-2pt,2pt)}]interior.south east); 
  },
overlay middle and last={
  \draw[myboxgray!70!black,fill=white] 
    ([shift={(2pt,-2pt)}]interior.north west) 
      rectangle 
    ([shift={(-2pt,2pt)}]interior.south east); 
  }  
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{mytemail}{HamiltonP, Beth}{Croft, Norrie}{September 12th 2014}{Paris}
\lipsum[4]
\end{mytemail}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

And now using the also powerful [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package:

[image]

All the job is now done by a `mymdemail` environment with four mandatory arguments:

```
\begin{mytemail}{<from>}{<to>}{<date>}{<subject>
<text>
\end{mytemail}
```

The box in the example was produced using

```
\begin{mymdemail}{HamiltonP, Beth}{Croft, Norrie}{September 12th 2014}{Paris}
\lipsum[4]
\end{mymdemail}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}% to generate text for the example

\definecolor{myboxgray}{RGB}{216,207,190}
\definecolor{mybackgray}{RGB}{243,232,223}

\def\mdfrom{\relax}
\def\mdto{\relax}
\def\mddate{\relax}
\def\mdsubj{\relax}

\tikzset{
mybox/.style={
  draw=myboxgray!70!black,
  fill=myboxgray,
  text width=1.3cm,
  anchor=north west,
  align=center,
  inner ysep=2pt,
  font=\sffamily\small  
  },
myinfobox/.style={
  draw=myboxgray!70!black,
  text width=\textwidth-2cm-1pt,
  anchor=north west,
  inner ysep=2pt,
  fill=white,
  font=\sffamily\small  
  }
}

\newmdenv[
linecolor=myboxgray!70!black,
innertopmargin=76pt,
splittopskip=19pt,
singleextra={
  \node[mybox]
    at ([shift={(2pt,-2pt)}]O|-P) 
    (from) {\strut From:};
  \node[mybox,below=2pt of from] 
    (to) {\strut To:};
  \node[mybox,below=2pt of to] 
    (date) {\strut Date:};
  \node[mybox,below=2pt of date] 
    (subj) {\strut Subject:};
  \node[draw,myinfobox,right=2pt of from] 
    (fromtext) {\strut\mdfrom};
  \node[draw,myinfobox,right=2pt of to] 
    (totext) {\strut\mdto};
  \node[draw,myinfobox,right=2pt of date] 
    (datetext) {\strut\mddate};
  \node[draw,myinfobox,right=2pt of subj] 
    (subjtext) {\strut\mdsubj};
  \draw[myboxgray!70!black] 
    ([shift={(2pt,-74pt)}]O|-P) --
    ([shift={(-2pt,-74pt)}]P) --
    ([shift={(-2pt,2pt)}]P|-O) --
    ([shift={(2pt,2pt)}]O) -- cycle;
  },
firstextra={
  \node[mybox]
    at ([shift={(2pt,-2pt)}]O|-P) 
    (from) {\strut From:};
  \node[mybox,below=2pt of from] 
    (to) {\strut To:};
  \node[mybox,below=2pt of to] 
    (date) {\strut Date:};
  \node[mybox,below=2pt of date] 
    (subj) {\strut Subject:};
  \node[draw,myinfobox,right=2pt of from] 
    (fromtext) {\strut\mdfrom};
  \node[draw,myinfobox,right=2pt of to] 
    (totext) {\strut\mdto};
  \node[draw,myinfobox,right=2pt of date] 
    (datetext) {\strut\mddate};
  \node[draw,myinfobox,right=2pt of subj] 
    (subjtext) {\strut\mdsubj};
  \draw[myboxgray!70!black] 
    ([shift={(2pt,-74pt)}]O|-P) --
    ([shift={(-2pt,-74pt)}]P) --
    ([shift={(-2pt,2pt)}]P|-O) --
    ([shift={(2pt,2pt)}]O) -- cycle;
  },
middleextra={
  \draw[myboxgray!70!black] 
    ([shift={(2pt,-2pt)}]O|-P) --
    ([shift={(-2pt,-2pt)}]P) --
    ([shift={(-2pt,2pt)}]P|-O) --
    ([shift={(2pt,2pt)}]O) -- cycle;
  },  
secondextra={
  \draw[myboxgray!70!black] 
    ([shift={(2pt,-2pt)}]O|-P) --
    ([shift={(-2pt,-2pt)}]P) --
    ([shift={(-2pt,2pt)}]P|-O) --
    ([shift={(2pt,2pt)}]O) -- cycle;
  },  
]{mdemail}

\newenvironment{mymdemail}[4]
  {%
    \gdef\mdfrom{#1}%
    \gdef\mdto{#2}%
    \gdef\mddate{#3}%
    \gdef\mdsubj{#4}%
    \begin{mdemail}
  }
  {\end{mdemail}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{mymdemail}{HamiltonP, Beth}{Croft, Norrie}{September 12th 2014}{Paris}
\lipsum[4]
\end{mymdemail}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: **Brilliant!** My favourite kind of answer! and what an answer, I couldn't ask for more. Thank you so much Gonzalo.

Comment: oh one tiny request ;) is it possible to add an _optional_ parameter to mytemail to indicate that there is an attachment? I know, I need to read more documentation and I'm just playing with it now so just maybe I'll figure it out!

Comment: I thought there was a placement error of the main text box but if I remove the "12pt" from my documentclass options it is placed correctly.

Comment: @susie You're welcome. Regarding the optional parameter, I have some questions. Do you want the `mytemail` environment to have an optional argument? Soething like `\begin{mytemail}[<optional>]{<from>}{<to>}{<date>}{<subject>
<text>
\end{mytemail}`? If so, what should be the effect of using this optional argument?

Comment: @susie I'll check the options later to improve the placement and make it independent of the size options passed to the class.

Comment: Sorry - been away from internet for a few days. Have been editing in the mytemail so my email chapter is looking much better now! wrt optional argument, it would be great if it was possible to have an optional box at the bottom probably stretching full width of the parent box that could contain the attachment file name(s) and maybe a save button?

Comment: I've been playing around with the mytemail environment and reading the documentation for tcolorbox(!) I've not managed to change the overall width of it. I was trying to make it slightly narrower than main text and central in the page... I'll keep reading!

Comment: @susie Ah, I see now what you meant by the optional argument for attachments; I am busy right now but as soon as I can I'll update the answer showing how to achieve this. Regarding the width of the box, I will also provide a way to achieve a narrower box (in the meantime, the `enlarge left by=<length>` and `width=<length>` are the options that allow you to achieve what you want).

Comment: You are a gem! I'll have a play with those options in the meantime.