# a line through a column in MathML

Tags: matrices, mathml

I have a problem with MathML.

How can I draw a line through a column (row and column at the same time) in a matrix?

An example in TEX:
[Draw a line through one column of a matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47730/draw-a-line-through-one-column-of-a-matrix)

Comment: Does MathML provide any tagging scheme for lines striking through row and column?

Comment: I found "verticalstrike" and "horizontalstrike", but I do not know how to use it with matrices.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MathML/Element/menclose

Comment: Thanks, have given a try and provided an example. Does that sound good enough?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 3):

The following code seems to work:

```
   \def\vs#1{\Tg<menclose notation="verticalstrike">#1\Tg</menclose>}
   \Css{.array mtd{padding-top: 0em; padding-bottom:0em;}}

   \begin{equation}
   \begin{pmatrix}
   \vs{a+b} & 12 & a+b+c\\
   \vs{c-d} & \gamma^2 & 0\\
   \vs{a}   & \alpha-\beta & abc\\
   \vs{c-d} & \psi_n & d\\
   \end{pmatrix}
   \end{equation}
```

If you have a working version of TeX4ht, you will get the following MathML output:

```
          <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"
          class="equation">
            <mfenced separators="" open="(" close=")">
              <mrow>
                <mtable style="text-align:axis;" equalrows="false"
                columnlines="none none none none none none none none none"
                equalcolumns="false" class="array">
                  <mtr>
                    <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
                      <menclose notation="verticalstrike">
                        <mi>a</mi>
                        <mo class="MathClass-bin">+</mo>
                        <mi>b</mi>
                      </menclose>
                    </mtd>
                    <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
                      <mn>1</mn>
                      <mn>2</mn>
                    </mtd>
                    <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
                      <mi>a</mi>
                      <mo class="MathClass-bin">+</mo>
                      <mi>b</mi>
                      <mo class="MathClass-bin">+</mo>
                      <mi>c</mi>
                    </mtd>
                  </mtr>
                  <mtr>
                    <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
                      <menclose notation="verticalstrike">
                        <mi>c</mi>
                        <mo class="MathClass-bin">-</mo>
                        <mi>d</mi>
                      </menclose>
                    </mtd>
                    <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
                      <msup>
                        <mrow>
                          <mi>&#947;</mi>
                        </mrow>
                        <mrow>
                          <mn>2</mn>
                        </mrow>
                      </msup>
                    </mtd>
                    <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
                      <mn>0</mn>
                    </mtd>
                  </mtr>
                  <mtr>
                    <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
                      <menclose notation="verticalstrike">
                        <mi>a</mi>
                      </menclose>
                    </mtd>
                    <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
                      <mi>&#945;</mi>
                      <mo class="MathClass-bin">-</mo>
                      <mi>&#946;</mi>
                    </mtd>
                    <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
                      <mi>a</mi>
                      <mi>b</mi>
                      <mi>c</mi>
                    </mtd>
                  </mtr>
                  <mtr>
                    <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
                      <menclose notation="verticalstrike">
                        <mi>c</mi>
                        <mo class="MathClass-bin">-</mo>
                        <mi>d</mi>
                      </menclose>
                    </mtd>
                    <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
                      <msub>
                        <mrow>
                          <mi>&#968;</mi>
                        </mrow>
                        <mrow>
                          <mi>n</mi>
                        </mrow>
                      </msub>
                    </mtd>
                    <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
                      <mi>d</mi>
                    </mtd>
                  </mtr>
                  <mtr>
                    <mtd class="array" columnalign="center"></mtd>
                  </mtr>
                </mtable>
              </mrow>
            </mfenced>
          </math>
```

The above MathML rendered in Firefox as [image: here]

Comment: I tested it:
http://s1.directupload.net/images/120916/vmbhchy5.png

Comment: Haven't you provided the \Css directive? Without suppressing top and bottom padding of <td> contents in the matrix array, the vertical rule will be broken across rows as in your example. Can you please confirm this?

Comment: A test with CSS-code "mtd{padding-top: 0em; padding-bottom:0em;}": http://s14.directupload.net/images/120917/qawbh7uj.png 

The exponents break the line.

Comment: I am clueless, can you please take a look at: http://download.river-valley.com/misc/sx4.html ?

Comment: And screenshot of the page as rendered in my browser is at http://download.river-valley.com/misc/vs.png

Comment: FF16/Win7: http://s14.directupload.net/images/120917/x9lx5czq.png

Comment: So, that is a browser problem. Mine is Firefox 15.0.1.

Comment: <mtable columnspacing="0em" rowspacing="0em"> could help, but it is still not so good, seems